# Solving and plotting PDEs with 2 parameters

Tags: differential-equations

I have some troubles on solving PDEs.

I want to plot the graph of $a^2(t)$ with varying constants $\rho$ and $l$. I tried this first.

```
pde = NDSolve[
{

(Derivative[1][a][t])^2/(a[t])^2 ==  l*(n[y])^2 + 0.1 * (a[t])^(-3),

2*Derivative[2][a][t]*a[t]*(b[t, y])^3 + 
2*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[1, 0][b][t, y]*a[t]*b[t, y] + 
Derivative[2][a][t]*a[t]*
b[t, y]*(n[y])^2 + (Derivative[1][a][t])^2 * (b[t, y])^3 + 
Derivative[2, 0][b][t, y]*(a[t]*b[t, y])^2 + 
Derivative[0, 1][b][t, y]*Derivative[1][n][y] ==   
l*(a[t])^2 * (b[t, y])^3 * (n[y])^2 + 
Derivative[2][n][y]*(a[t])^2  * b[t, y]*n[y],

3*( Derivative[2][a][t]) *(b[t, y])^2 / (a[t] * (n[y])^2) + 
3 (Derivative[1][a][t])^2/(a[t])^2 * (b[t, y] / n[y])^2  - 
l * (b[t, y])^2 == 0

a[0] == 0,
b[0, y] == 0,
b[t, 0] == 0
n[0] == 1

},

a [t], n[y], b[t, y],

{t, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}]
```

and it resulted this error:

```
NDSolve::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected
instead of True in the first argument"
```

but i can't find what is wrong. second time i tried without boundary condition. then it says:

```
NDSolve::conarg: "The arguments should be ordered consistently"
```

I can't find which argument is ordered inconsistently. Please help me.

Thank you.

---

Thank you for comments. I fixed small problems. but still there is problem. the fixed code is here.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 100}, {-100, 100}]
pde = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(Derivative[1][a][t])^2/(a[t])^2 == 
l*(n[y])^2 + rho*(a[t])^(-3), 
2*Derivative[2][a][t]*a[t]*(b[t, y])^3 + 
 2*Derivative[1][a][t]*Derivative[1, 0][b][t, y]*a[t]*b[t, y] + 
 Derivative[2][a][t]*a[t]*
  b[t, y]*(n[y])^2 + (Derivative[1][a][t])^2*(b[t, y])^3 + 
 Derivative[2, 0][b][t, y]*(a[t]*b[t, y])^2 + 
 Derivative[0, 1][b][t, y]*Derivative[1][n][y] == 
l*(a[t])^2*(b[t, y])^3*(n[y])^2 + 
 Derivative[2][n][y]*(a[t])^2*b[t, y]*n[y], 
3*(Derivative[2][a][t])*(b[t, y])^2/(a[t]*(n[y])^2) + 
 3 (Derivative[1][a][t])^2/(a[t])^2*(b[t, y]/n[y])^2 - 
 l*(b[t, y])^2 == 0, a[0] == 0, b[0, y] == 0, b[t, 0] == 0 , 
n[0] == 1}, a, {x, t} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {rho, l}]
```

so far there's no problem. but when i tried to find specific solution

```
if1 = pde[1, 1]
```

it says:

```
ParametricNDSolveValue::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation
```

how can I fix it? and I also want to plot the graph. I used the normal plot function and got the same error.

Comment: my equation is here:

$$
\frac{a'(t)^2}{a(t)^2}=\frac{\rho}{a(t)^3}+l n(y)^2
$$

$$
a(t) n(y)^2 a''(t) b(t,y)+2 a(t) a''(t) b(t,y)^3+2 a(t) a'(t) b_{t}(t,y) b(t,y)+a'(t)^2 b(t,y)^3+a(t)^2 b_{tt}(t,y) b(t,y)^2+n'(y) b_{y}(t,y)=l a(t)^2 n(y)^2 b(t,y)^3+a(t)^2 n(y) n''(y) b(t,y)
$$

$$
\frac{3 a''(t) b(t,y)^2}{a(t) n(y)^2}+\frac{3 a'(t)^2 b(t,y)^2}{a(t)^2 n(y)^2}-l b(t,y)^2=0
$$


here $\rho$ and $l$ is some constant.

Comment: You code is missing some commas and brackets. Please check your syntax.

Comment: Take a look at `ParametricNDSolveValue`

Comment: Try a simpler example first, also try using `a[t,y]`, `n[t,y]` and `b[t,y]`

Comment: I edited some mistakes. Could you see it again, please?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48033/pde-combined-with-ode-1d