# Variation of heat equation with guessed initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, boundary-condition-at-infinity, heat-equation

Hi I am trying to solve a variation of the heat equation with interaction terms and external source -- actually it's the Schrödinger-Newton equation if that's more familiar to you.
\begin{align}
  i  \dot \psi
  & =
  -\nabla^2 \psi +   \psi \phi_N
  +
  |\psi|^2\psi,
  \cr
  \nabla^2 \phi_N
  & =
  |\psi|^2,
\end{align}

The boundary condition is that $\psi, \phi$ both vanish at large radius and its first derivative vanishes at zero:

\begin{align}
\frac{d \psi}{d r}(0,t) &= 0, \cr
\psi(\infty,t) &= 0, \cr
\frac{d \phi}{d r}(0,t) &= 0, \cr
\phi(\infty,t) &= 0. 
\end{align}

The exact form of initial condition is not known and the requirement is the wave function being real at t=0, it vanishes at $r$ being large. 
Since NDSolve requires an explicit initial condition, 
I've been trying the following code with a guessed initial condition:

\begin{align}
\psi(r,0) &= (1+r) \mathrm{e}^{-r}, \cr
\phi(r,0) &=\phi_0(r),
\end{align} where $\phi_0(r)$ is the solution of $\nabla^2 \phi = (1+r)^2 \mathrm{e}^{-2r}$, with $\frac{d \phi_0}{d r} (0) = 0$, and $\phi_0(\infty) = 0$.

So far I haven't got much success to run the code. The kernel complains about zero differential order(`pdord`), inconsistency (`ibcinc`), insufficient number of boundary conditions (`bcart`), unable to continue with complex values (`mconly`), and unable to find initial conditions that satisfy (`icfail`). Is there any way to solve it with NDSolve?

```
tmpψinitial[r_] := (1 + r)*E^(-r)
tmpϕinitial[rr_] := DSolveValue[{D[ϕ[r], r, r] == (1 + r)^2* E^(-2 r),(D[ϕ[r], r] /. r -> 0) == 0, ϕ[rEnd0] == 10^-4}, ϕ[r], r] /. r -> rr
rStart0 = 0.01;
rEnd0 = 5;
epsilon=10^-5;

eqn = {-I*D[ψ[r, t], t] - 1/2*(D[ψ[r, t], r, r] 
        + 2/r*D[ψ[r, t], r]) + ψ[r, t]*ψ[r, t]* Conjugate[ψ[r, t]] + ψ[r, t]*ϕ[r, t] == 0
, 2/r*D[ϕ[r, t], r] + D[ϕ[r, t], r, r] == Conjugate[ψ[r, t]]*ψ[r, t]};

ic = {ψ[r, 0] == tmpψinitial[r], ϕ[r, 0] == tmpϕinitial[r]};
bc = {(D[ψ[r, t], r] /. r -> rStart0)== epsilon
 , (D[ϕ[r, t], r]/. r -> rStart0) == epsilon
 , ψ[rEnd0, t] == epsilon
 , ϕ[rEnd0, t] == epsilon};

sol = NDSolveValue[Flatten@{eqn, ic, bc}, {ψ, ϕ}, {r, rStart0, rEnd0}, {t, 0, 10}, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
```

Comment: (a) Is this 1D, or 2D/3D with radial symmetry? (b) your guessed initial condition does not have vanishing derivative at $r=0$, is that on purpose? (c) I suspect your question is not well defined. Is there a single possible initial condition? are you looking for _any_ consistent initial condition or a _specific_ one?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. a) this is the S-N equation in 3D with spherical symmetry. So the laplacian is $2/r \frac{d}{dr} + \frac{d^2}{dr^2}$. b) actually the first derivative of $(1+r) e^{-r}$ at $r=0$ does vanish. c) Because this question is physically motivated, actually it is not possible to find the exact initial condition. In the literature, either $\sim (1+r) e^{-r}$, or simply Gaussian distribution is used. To put it another way, I'm looking for a solution for a type of consistent initial conditions (exponential function of power of $r$, function vanishes when r goes large.)

Comment: Sorry I mean the requirements for the initial condition are just 1) spherically symmetric, $i.e.$ it only depends on $r$, 2) the function goes to zero as $r$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note**
>
> A bug of `ComplexExpand` is introduced after *v11.3*, in or before
> *v12.3*, and persists through 13.0. The code in this answer is influenced. Please fix `ComplexExpand` using workarounds in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269893/1871) before
> trying the code below.

`ibcinc` warning isn't a big deal here, because the i.c. and b.c. are almost consistent. The hard part is `pdord` warning. (`bcart`, `mconly` and `icfail` are probably by-products of it. )

`pdord` pops up because the equation system doesn't explicitly contain derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $t$, and several previous questions in this site suggest that, `NDSolve` just can't directly handle this type of problem well at the moment (probably due to the not-strong-enough DAE solver). So we need to transform the equation a bit to help `NDSolve` to use an ODE solver to solve it.

We first separate real and imaginary part of the equation because `Conjugate` turns out to be hard to handle in later step:

```
rStart0 = 1/100;
rEnd0 = 5;
epsilon = 0(*1/10^5*);

tmpψinitial[r_] := (1 + r) E^-r
tmpϕinitial[r_] = 
  DSolve[{D[ϕ[r], r, r] == (1 + r)^2 E^(-2 r), (D[ϕ[r], r] /. r -> 0) == 
      epsilon, ϕ[rEnd0] == epsilon}, ϕ[r], r][[1, 1, -1]];


Unevaluated[
  eqn = {-I*D[ψ[r, t], t] - 
      1/2*(D[ψ[r, t], r, r] + 2/r*D[ψ[r, t], r]) + ψ[r, t]*ψ[r, t]*
       Conjugate[ψ[r, t]] + ψ[r, t]*ϕ[r, t] == 0, 
    2/r*D[ϕ[r, t], r] + D[ϕ[r, t], r, r] == 
     Conjugate[ψ[r, t]]*ψ[r, t]};
  
  ic = {ψ[r, 0] == tmpψinitial[r], ϕ[r, 0] == tmpϕinitial[r]};
  bc = {(D[ψ[r, t], r] /. r -> rStart0) == 
     epsilon, (D[ϕ[r, t], r] /. r -> rStart0) == epsilon, ψ[rEnd0, t] == 
     epsilon, ϕ[rEnd0, t] == 
     epsilon};] /. {ψ -> (psiR[#, #2] + I psiI[#, #2] &), ϕ -> (phiR[#, #2] + 
      I phiI[#, #2] &)};


systemnew = {repart, impart} = ComplexExpand@Map[#, {eqn, ic, bc}, {3}] & /@ {Re, Im};
```

Next we add derivative with respect to `t` to the 2nd equation:

```
addD = MapAt[D[#, t] &, #, {1, 2}] &;
{eqnfinal, icfinal, bcfinal} = Transpose[addD /@ systemnew];
```

Still, `NDSolve` isn't able to handle `eqnfinal` (I believe it's related to [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118194/1871)), so we need to discretize the system to an ODE system all by ourselves. I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task:

```
points = 25; domain = {rStart0, rEnd0}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
difforder = 4;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *) 
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{psiR, psiI, phiR, phiI}[r, t], t, grid, difforder];

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ode = Map[del, ptoofunc[eqnfinal], {2}];

odeic = ptoofunc@icfinal;

odebc = With[{sf = 1}, ptoofunc@diffbc[t, sf]@bcfinal];

tend = 10;
```

The last step is to solve the discretized system. Directly solving `{ode, odeic, odebc}` with `NDSolve` is OK, but when `points` becomes large (increasing `points` is perhaps the most efficient way for increasing precision in this case), the pre-processing inside `NDSolve` will become very slow (it internally use `Solve` to transform the system, for more information you may check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871)), so, again, we need to transform the system by ourselves outside of `NDSolve`, with the help of `CoeffcientArrays` and `LinearSolve`, given the system is a linear system for derivatives with respect to `t`:

```
(* The following can be used but is slow: *)
(*  
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, 
   Outer[#[#2] &, {psiR, psiI, phiR, phiI}, grid], {t, 0, tend}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"} ];
*)
(* More advanced but faster approach: *)
lhs = D[Flatten@Outer[#[#2][t] &, {psiR, psiI, phiR, phiI}, grid], t];
{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[Flatten[{ode, odebc}], lhs]; // AbsoluteTiming
rhs = LinearSolve[m, -b]; // AbsoluteTiming

sollst = NDSolveValue[{odeic, lhs == rhs // Thread}, 
    Outer[#[#2] &, {psiR, psiI, phiR, phiI}, grid], {t, 0, tend}, 
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming

sol = rebuild[#, grid, 2] & /@ sollst

label = {Re@ψ, Im@ψ, Re@ϕ, Im@ϕ};

Partition[Table[
   Plot3D[sol[[i]][r, t], #, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> label[[i]]] &@
    Flatten@{r, domain}, {i, 4}], 2] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

BTW, the following is a even more advanced but even faster approach to solve for `sol`:

```
varlst = Flatten@Outer[#[#2][t] &, {psiR, psiI, phiR, phiI}, grid];
varmid = Compile`GetElement[lst, #] & /@ Range@Length@varlst;
crhs = Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}}, #, 
     RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False] &[
   rhs /. Thread[varlst -> varmid]];
iclst = LinearSolve[#2, -#] & @@ CoefficientArrays[Flatten@odeic, varlst /. t -> 0];
solvector = 
   NDSolveValue[{vector[0] == iclst, vector'[t] == crhs@vector[t]}, vector, {t, 0, tend},
     MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming

sol = ListInterpolation[#, {grid, solvector["Coordinates"][[1]]}] & /@ 
   Partition[Transpose@Developer`ToPackedArray@solvector["ValuesOnGrid"], points];
```

Comment: Thank you much for the detailed explanation. This is very helpful! Actually I did notice that simply adding a time derivative term could solve the system although it altered the equation. Am I right to think that you added a total derivative on both sides of the second equation just to tell Mathematica to choose the right PDE solver?

Comment: @BosonBear To be precise, it's for making _Mathematica_ use an ODE solver rather than a DAE solver for solving the discretized system. If we don't differential the 2nd equation, after discretization the 2nd equation will become a set of algebraic equations that doesn't involve derivative of `t`, so `NDSolve` will choose a DAE solver for solving it, which doesn't work well on this problem. (You'll see `icfail` then. ) BTW the seemingly strange definition of `odebc` is also for adding derivative of `t` to the boundary condition.

Comment: I see. So when I plot it out at a slice of `r` with respect to `t`, the plot is a bit zig-zag due to numerical noise. I wonder what the most efficient way is in order to increase the precision in the `t` direction?

Comment: @BosonBear Increasing the spatial grid points (in this case `points`) is almost the only way, as far as I know, but then the previous approach turns out to be slow. I've edited the post the include a more efficient approach, check the edit. BTW, a quick test shows, `difforder=2` seems to be accurate enough for the system and make the calculation faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm working on a project where solving this efficiently is part of it. Since you've helped me a lot in the past a few days, I wonder if there's any way to acknowledge it properly in my paper if the work comes to fruition. Cheers!

Comment: @BosonBear There already exist discussions about this topic in meta :) : https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/968/1871  https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/1871

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to it! Actually, I was thinking about acknowledging your contribution in the acknowledgement section of my paper, adding citation, or even future collaboration on a few physics motivated numerical problems. I guess that involves too much personal info so I totally understand if you prefer to being anonymous. Otherwise, drop me a line at cphysc@gmail.com if you would like to chat a lil bit. Also, I have a somehow related question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164218/ndsolve-eigenvalue-problem-of-bound-state). Any comment is welcome