# Solve PDEs with finite difference scheme by modifying NDSolve-based solver

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, syntax, finite-difference-method

**Motivation**

As discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129183/ndsolve-uses-different-difference-order-for-different-spatial-derivative-when-so), `NDSolve` uses different difference orders for various spatial derivatives and the implicit design could cause trouble in certain cases.
Thus, it may be useful to specify the difference order for spatial derivatives as well as customize difference scheme for time advance in some applications. And that's why I'm trying to use a finite difference method (FDM) encoded in `NDSolve` to construct a lower-level PDE solver instead of using the high-level `NDSolve` black box directly.

**Problem**

Consider a system of PDEs which will be solved with specified FDM encoded in
`myFDM[points, xdifforder, torder]`:

```
secondDop[x_, α_] = (D[#, {x, 2}] - (α^2 + 1)*#) &; (*define a differential operator*)
With[{a = a[t, x], b = b[t, x], c = c[t, x], q = q[t, x], U = x},
 eq = {I*α*a - D[b, x] + I*c == 0,
   -D[a, t] == 1/m*secondDop[x, α][a] - I*α*U*a - I α q,
   -D[b, t] == -a*D[U, x] + 1/m*secondDop[x, α][b] - 
     I*α*U*b + D[q, x],
   -D[c, t] == 1/m*secondDop[x, α][c] - I*α*U*c - I*q};
 (* values in ICs could be adjusted to allow the code to be run *)
 ic = {a == 1-x^2, b == Sin[x π], c == 0, q == 1} /. t -> endtime;
 bc = {{a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, q == 1} /. 
    x -> -1, {a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, q == 1} /. x -> 1};]

endtime = 5; points = 100;
m=200;
xdifforder = 2; torder = 2; (* Difference orders in x and t *)
grid = Array[# &, points, {-1, 1}]; (*spatial points separated by a distance of 2/points*)
bsol=NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, {a, b, c, q}, {t, endtime, 0}, {x, -1, 1},
  Method -> [myFDM[points, xdifforder, torder]]]
```

**Specifications and Questions**

I believe the desired function `myFDM` should be a modification of the `pdetoode` solver developed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997) by xzczd with the following significant differences. (Although I have learned Wolfram language for a long time some parts in `pdetoode` are still confusing for me, e.g. the line to *remove redundant equations from every PDE/IC* in `moveredundant`...)

1. My problem includes **4 PDEs** instead of one PDE;
2. These PDEs will be **integrated from `endtime` to `0`** due to mathematical reasons, i.e. backward, as implied by the minus sign before each time derivative term on the LHS.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean you want to define a custom method for `NDSolve` to solve the PDE system, similar to those introduced in `tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta`? If so, I should say it's very hard, if not impossible. `ExplicitRungeKutta` seems to be the only method that can be highly customized in `NDSolve`, at least according to the introduction in the document. That's the reason I create `pdetoode`, `fix` etc. attempting to break the limitation somewhat _outside_ of `NDSolve`. BTW, your problem is similar to this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163923/1871 The bottleneck is `eq[[1]]`.

Comment: Thanks@xzczd Reply: R1. nope, I didn't mean to define a totally custom method. I want to explicitly discretize the spatial derivative with `pdetoode` and fix the order of the derivatives, then solve the obtained ODEs. R2. yes, `eq[[1]]` is hard to handle due to the absence of time derivative. From above link I realized that `D` on `eq[[1]]` allows `NDSolve` to choose an ODE solver. Questions: Q1. In `pdetoode`, can u explicitly choose the spatial scheme, say, 2nd-order central difference? Did u mean it's impossible or very hard to control time-marching scheme in `NDSolve` even with `pdetoode`?

Comment: 1. When the 4th parameter of `pdetoode` is set to `2`, 2nd order central difference formula is chosen for all the grid points except for those on the boundary, you can play with a coarse grid, say, `Array[#&, 5, {0,1}]` and observe the resulting system. 2. By "customize" I mean creating something not built-in. If you just want to _control_ the ODE solver, it's not hard, but do notice the ODE solver is robust enough and don't need any manual adjustion in most cases, the bottleneck for PDE solving is almost always the spatial discretization.

Comment: Also, notice a simple `D[eq[[1]], t]` won't invoke ODE solver, because the system still doesn't involve `D[q, t]` term afterwards.

Comment: What is the actual question you have?

Comment: @xzczd as for Q2 in my post, to integrate PDE from `endtime` to 0, don't we need additional modifications in `NDSolve` or/and `pdetoode`, except modifying `ic` and time limit in `{t, endtime, 0}`?

Comment: Well, if you have difficulty in understanding the source code of `pdetoode`, then it's not too bad an idea to let it alone. You just need to know it's usage. As to the removing step, notice `ptoofunc` generates discretized equation on every grid points, so we need to delete some of them to _make room_ for those i.c.s/b.c.s. Is your basic goal solving this PDE system? If so, I can post an answer.

Comment: @user21 the actual question is: for a system of pdes with given 'ICs' at `endtime`, how to find the functions at `t=0` by explicitly encoding a FD scheme in `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned above, this problem is somewhat similar to, but even more troublesome than [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163923/1871), because there seems to be no obvious way to discretize and transform the PDE system to an ODE system. To be more specific, it's hard to introduce derivative of $q$ with respect to $t$ without causing other trouble. So, let's give up `NDSolve` and turn to pure finite difference method (FDM). It's not too hard to achieve with the help of [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).

Definitions for `eq`, `ic`, `bc` are the same as those in the question. `α` isn't specified in the question so I simply choose `1`.

```
Clear[grid, points]
begintime = 0; endtime = 5; 
points@x = 200; points@t = 25;
m = 200;
difforder = 8;
domain@x = {-1, 1}; domain@t = {begintime, endtime};
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, t};

(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)    
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{a, b, c, q}[t, x], grid /@ {t, x}, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = Map[del, Most /@ ptoafunc@eq, {2}];
aeic = del /@ ptoafunc@ic;
aebc = ptoafunc@bc;
var = Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {a, b, c, q}, grid@t, grid@x];
{barray, marray} = 
   CoefficientArrays[Flatten@{ae, aeic, aebc}, Flatten@var]; // AbsoluteTiming
Block[{α = 1}, sollst = LinearSolve[N@marray, -barray]]; // AbsoluteTiming
solmatlst = ArrayReshape[sollst, var // Dimensions];
solfunclst = ListInterpolation[#, grid /@ {t, x}] & /@ solmatlst;
plot[f_, style_, t_] := 
 Plot[solfunclst[t, x] // Through // f // Evaluate, {x, domain@x} // Flatten // Evaluate,
   PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotStyle -> style]
Manipulate[GraphicsRow@{plot[Re, Automatic, t], plot[Im, Dashed, t]}, {t, endtime, 
  begintime}]
```

[image]

Notice the setting `difforder = 8` is important here, or the solution of `q` will be noisy.

Also, the behavior of `q` near the boundary seems to suggest the b.c.s for $q$ might be redudant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88615/discussion-on-answer-by-xzczd-solve-pdes-with-finite-difference-scheme-by-modify).