# Dynamic, nonlinear, damped Euler–Bernoulli beam equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, physics

I would like to solve the 3 coupled PDEs describing a damped, nonlinear (i.e displacements in the $x$ direction along the beam need to be considered along with the $y$ displacements normally considered), inextensible, euler-bernoulli cantilever beam's motion. The equations are as follows:

1: where $u(t,s)$ is the displacement in the $x$ direction
$$\mu\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+k\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\lambda\left(1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)\right)=0$$
2: where $v(t,s)$ is the displacement in the $y$ direction

**EDIT: To make things simpler, we expand the elasticity term to first order only.**
$$\mu\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2}+k\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\lambda\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right)+EI\frac{\partial^4 v}{\partial s^4}=0$$
3: inextensibility of beam condition
$$\left(1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right)^2-1=0$$
$\mu$, $EI$ and $k$ are constants representing mass density, stiffness and drag coefficient, while **EDIT: $\lambda(t,s)$ is the lagrange multiplier needed to maintain the inextensibility condition.**

My boundary conditions are as follows (for a beam of unit length):

**EDIT: New b.c.s. that include $\lambda(t,s)$**

**2 for $u$**

$u(t,0)=0$

$\lambda(t,1)\left(1+u^{(0,1)}(t,1)\right)=0$

**4 for $v$**

$v(t,0)=0$

$v^{(0,1)}(t,0)=0$

$v^{(0,2)}(t,1)=0$

$EI\left(v^{(0,3)}(t,1)\right)-\lambda(t,1)v^{(0,1)}(t,1)=1$

**EDIT: I use a point load of 1N at the end of the beam to perturb it instead so the beam is completely stationary in the i.c.s**

Next, my initial conditions are of a fully stationary, straight beam:

$u(0,x)=0$

$u^{(1,0)}(0,x)=0$

$v(0,x)=0$

$v^{(1,0)}(0,x)=0$

My approach is to use the [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997) function by @xzczd. I had no problems following and implementing the solution for the linearized Euler-Bernoulli equation as in [this earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127990) (that is, only **small** deflections in the $y$ direction are considered and inextensibility is ignored), but I have issues with generating the correct number of ODEs for NDSolve to solve for the nonlinear system.

Here is my implementation within Mathematica:

**EDIT: Here is the code with the updated functions and b.c.s.**

```
μ = 1; 
EI = 10; 
k = 1; 
eqn1 = μ*D[u[t, s], {t, 2}] + k*D[u[t, s], t] - 
    D[λ[t, s]*(1 + D[u[t, s], s]), s] == 0; 
eqn2 = μ*D[v[t, s], {t, 2}] + k*D[v[t, s], t] - 
    D[λ[t, s]*D[v[t, s], s], s] + EI*D[v[t, s], {s, 4}] == 0; 
eqn3 = (1 + D[u[t, s], s])^2 + D[v[t, s], s]^2 - 1 == 0; 
bc1 = {u[t, 0] == 0, λ[t, 1]*(1 + Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 1]) == 
    0}; 
bc2 = {v[t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][v][t, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 2][v][t, 1] == 0, 
   EI*Derivative[0, 3][v][t, 1] - λ[t, 1]*
      Derivative[0, 1][v][t, 1] == 1}; 
ic1 = {u[0, s] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][0, s] == 0}; 
ic2 = {v[0, s] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][v][0, s] == 0};
```

Generate the finite-difference grid (i use 9 points for now to speed things up but more would be needed for accuracy):

```
lb = 0;
rb = 1;
torder = 2;
sdifforder = 2;

points = 9;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];
```

Generate ODEs using [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997):

```
removeredundant1 = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
removeredundant2 = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

ptoofunc = pdetoode[{u, v, λ}[t, s], t, grid, sdifforder];

odeqn1 = eqn1 // ptoofunc // removeredundant1;
odeqn2 = eqn2 // ptoofunc // removeredundant2;
odeqn3 = eqn3 // ptoofunc;
odeic1 = Flatten[removeredundant1 /@ ptoofunc@ic1];
odeic2 = Flatten[removeredundant2 /@ ptoofunc@ic2];
odebc1 = bc1 // ptoofunc;
odebc2 = bc2 // ptoofunc;
```

**EDIT: For the ODEs generated from eqn 1 and i.c. 1, I remove 2 equations to make space for 2 b.c.s. For the ODEs generated from eqn 2 and i.c. 2, I remove 4 equations to make space for 4 b.c.s. I remove no equations from the ODEs generated from eqn 3. The system is now correctly determined and I no longer get the error `NDSolve::overdet`:**

```
tEnd = 1;
sollst = NDSolveValue[
   Join[odebc1, odebc2, odeic1, odeic2, odeqn1, odeqn2, odeqn3], 
   Join[u /@ grid, v /@ grid, λ /@ grid], {t, 0, tEnd}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

**Now, the issue is as follows:**

> NDSolveValue::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.

Comment: How was this system obtained?

Comment: As far as I understand, the 3rd unknown function to be calculated is the lagrange multiplier $\lambda(t)$. The first two equations are derived from the Euler-Lagrange equation with the lagrange multiplier being the force required to maintain inextensibility. Drag is accounted for with the extended hamiltonian principle. The last term in eqn 2 is obtained by expanding the elasticity term in the lagrangian to 4th order.

Comment: @xzczd I have extensively edited the post with changes made to the PDEs and the b.c.s and i.c.s. Now the system is correctly determined, but NDSolve cannot find satisfactory initial conditions.

Comment: Now the undelying problem is probably similar to the one mentioned in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183767/1871), you may refer to it. I'm in a hurry at the moment, if you still have difficulty in resolving the problem, I can try fixing your code later, maybe tonight.

Comment: It is only a comment, maybe an irrelevant one. There is a statement of the problem for such a rod, that is more simple and yields equations of the second, rather than of the fourth order. It works like this due to a nonlinear transform done from the very beginning. If you are interested, have a look at L. D. Landau and E. M. Lifshitz, Theory of Elasticity, 3 ed. (Pergamon Press, Oxford, 1986), Problems 1 to 4 for § 19. These problems are for the static case, but the generalization to the dynamic one seems rather straightforward.

Comment: @xzczd thanks, I'm looking into it. That said, time-domain discretization is rather unideal for my eventual application goal because I will be needing to trigger piecewise conditions and possibly even use `WhenEvent` (these methods are already working for me for the lineaerized equtions).

Comment: At this juncture, I am still stuck with the same error. I am more inclined to think this problem is related to the solving method rather than an incorrect formulation of equations, because I found a reference that formulates similar equations to myself for a similar system:

Yabuno, Hiroshi, et al. "Suppression of parametric resonance in cantilever beam with a pendulum (Effect of static friction at the supporting point of the pendulum)." Journal of vibration and acoustics 126.1 (2004): 149-162.

Comment: That shouldn't be physically correct, since my 4th boundary condition on $v$ specifies a point load on the end of the cantilever.

Comment: My experience in solving the inextensible nonlinear beam was that it is much easier to solve in terms of intrinsic variables such as the curvature than the position x and y, because you can get rid of the inextensibility constraint that way. Also you may want to include a pair of false points in the discretization rather than just drop two points to include the boundary conditions, as I found that induced significant errors around the ends of the beam.

Comment: @KraZug "… you may want to include a pair of false points in the discretization…" Do you mean ghost-point? If so, it probably won't improve the accuracy in this case because AFAIK it's equivalent to high order one-sided difference formula, which is implemented in ``NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative`` (the function inside `pdetoode` and `pdetoae` ). For more information about one-sided formula, you may check the content started from page 6 of [this book](https://disciplinas.stoa.usp.br/pluginfile.php/41896/mod_resource/content/1/LeVeque%20Finite%20Diff.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure if solving in terms of intrinsic variables is the way to go either, since the WhenEvent[] conditions I'm planning to apply down the line are direct functions of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @xzczd, yes I mean ghost points. I was using `NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative` too (I was basically doing exactly what `pdetoode` does, but the hard way), and I found that adding the phantom points fixed the unphysical issues I was having.

Comment: You can solve for the angle/curvature and the positions simultaneously. A 6th order system in terms of angle and the Lagrange multiplier plus the 2 integrals for x and y is easier than a 9th order differential algebraic system of order 3.

Comment: @Unevaluated-Sequence The Lagrange multiplier and the inextensibility condition can be eliminated from the system of equations, see https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/28301/Thesis.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @KraZug I have to retract my earlier statement "Ghost point is equivalent to high order one-sided difference formula", after careful comparison I notice there does exist subtle difference. I need to explore more to see if this difference causes something amazing in certain cases though. Is the example you encountered posted in this site?

Comment: @xzczd, I don't think I posted it here. I'll see if I can dig the code out though.

Comment: @Unevaluated-Sequence, did you original question get answered?

Answer (score 8):

For those values `u, v` that arise in this problem, we can use eqn3 for finding `u`. The equation for `v` can be solved by the usual "MethodOfLines", for example

```
f[x_] := x;
μ = 1;
EI = 10;
k = 1;
λ[t_] := 1
eqn1 = μ*D[u[t, s], {t, 2}] + k*D[u[t, s], t] - 
    D[λ[t]*(1 + D[u[t, s], s]), s] == 0;
eqn2 = μ*D[v[t, s], {t, 2}] + k*D[v[t, s], t] - 
    D[λ[t]*D[v[t, s], s], s] + 
    EI*(D[(1 + D[v[t, s], s]^2 + D[v[t, s], s]^4)*
         D[v[t, s], {s, 2}], {s, 2}] + 
       D[(1 + (1/2)*D[v[t, s], s]^2)*D[v[t, s], {s, 2}]^2, s]) == 0;
eqn3 = (1 + D[u[t, s], s])^2 + D[v[t, s], s]^2 - 1 == 0;
ic1 = {u[0, s] == 0};
ic2 = {v[0, s] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][v][0, s] == f[s]};
bc1 = {u[t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0};
bc2 = {v[t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][v][t, 0] == f[0], 
   Derivative[0, 3][v][t, 1] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][v][t, 1] == 1};
tEnd = 1;

sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eqn2, ic2, bc2}, v, {t, 0, tEnd}, {s, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 25, "MaxPoints" ->25, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
```

Use `pdetoode` to solve this problem and compare two solutions.

```
lb = 0; rb = 1;

torder = 2;

xdifforder = 2;

points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];


removeredundant = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

ptoofunc = pdetoode[v[t, s], t, grid, xdifforder];

odeqn = eqn2 // ptoofunc // removeredundant;
odeic = removeredundant /@ ptoofunc@ic2;
odebc = bc2 // ptoofunc;


sollst = NDSolveValue[{odebc, odeic, odeqn}, v /@ grid, {t, 0, tEnd}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity];

sol = ListInterpolation[
   Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ sollst // 
    Transpose, {Flatten@sollst[[1]]["Grid"], grid}];

{ContourPlot[sol1[t, s], {t, 0, tEnd}, {s, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"t", "s"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "Method Of Lines"], 
 ContourPlot[sol[t, x], {t, 0, tEnd}, {x, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"t", "s"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> "pdetoode"]}
```

[image: fig1]

Solutions do not match. Which method is wrong? For `"MethodOfLines"`, we have two messages.

```
NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.

NDSolveValue::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 1642.781029898344` at t = 1.` in the direction of independent variable s is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 25 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options.
```

For `pdetoode`  there is no messages. As advised by  xzczd, we will add options to

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eqn2, ic2, bc2}, v, {t, 0, tEnd}, {s, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, 
       "ScaleFactor" -> 100}, 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MaxPoints" -> 25, "MinPoints" -> 25, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}},
    MaxSteps -> 10^6];
```

then the results become similar, although they do not match
[image: fig2]

Now we have to solve the original problem.The system of equations of the third order in powers of amplitude is given by [Pramod Malatkar. Nonlinear Vibrations of Cantilever Beams and Plates](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/28301/Thesis.pdf?sequence=1) - see eqs (2.54), (2.55), (2, 56), (2.57). We put $w = 0, Q_u = 0, D_\zeta = EI, Q_v = f (t) $ and use the method of the false transient and method of lines with `pdetoode`

```
Clear[f];
f[t_] := Sin[2*Pi*t];
μ = 1;
EI = 10;
k = 1;
c = 0;
dif = 1/100; tm = 8;
eqn1 = D[F[t, s], {s, 2}] - dif*D[F[t, s], t] - 
    D[D[v[t, s], s]^2, {t, 2}] == 0;
eqn2 = μ*D[v[t, s], {t, 2}] + k*D[v[t, s], t] + 
    c*D[v[t, s], t]*Abs[D[v[t, x], t]] + EI*D[v[t, s], {s, 4}] + 
    EI*(D[D[v[t, s], s]*D[D[v[t, s], s]*D[v[t, s], {s, 2}], s], 
       s]) + μ/2*D[D[v[t, s], s]*F[t, s], s] - f[t] == 0;

ic1 = {F[0, s] == 0};
ic2 = {v[0, s] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][v][0, s] == 0};
bc1 = {F[t, 0] == 0, F[t, 1] == 0};
bc2 = {v[t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][v][t, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 3][v][t, 1] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][v][t, 1] == 0};
lb = 0; rb = 1;

torder = 4;

xdifforder = 2;

points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];

removeredundant1 = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
removeredundant2 = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

ptoofunc = pdetoode[{F[t, s], v[t, s]}, t, grid, xdifforder];
odeqn1 = eqn1 // ptoofunc // removeredundant1;
odeic1 = removeredundant1 /@ ptoofunc@ic1;
odebc1 = bc1 // ptoofunc;
odeqn2 = eqn2 // ptoofunc // removeredundant2;
odeic2 = removeredundant2 /@ ptoofunc@ic2;
odebc2 = bc2 // ptoofunc;


sollst = NDSolveValue[{odebc1, odeic1, odeqn1, odebc2, odeic2, 
    odeqn2}, v /@ grid, {t, 0, tm}];

sol = ListInterpolation[
   Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ sollst // 
    Transpose, {Flatten@sollst[[1]]["Grid"], grid}];

sollst1 = 
 NDSolveValue[{odebc1, odeic1, odeqn1, odebc2, odeic2, odeqn2}, 
  F /@ grid, {t, 0, tm}]; sol1 = 
 ListInterpolation[
  Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ sollst1 // 
   Transpose, {Flatten@sollst1[[1]]["Grid"], grid}];

    {ContourPlot[sol1[t, x], {t, 0, tm}, {x, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"t", "s"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "F"], 

 ContourPlot[sol[t, x], {t, 0, tm}, {x, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"t", "s"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "v"], 
 Plot[sol1[t, .5], {t, 0, tm}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "F"], 
     Plot[sol[t, 1], {t, 0, tm}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "v"]}
```

here `F[]` is similar to $\lambda $

[image: fig3]

Comment: How is eqn 1 accounted for? Also as per my edits in the OP, $\lambda$ is a function of both $s$ and $t$ and is the 3rd unknown parameter to be solved for. The system is now correctly determined.

Comment: Yes, but this is a completely different problem. Who will be in time for your thought?

Comment: Yup, I wasn't expecting you to have accounted for it, was merely telling you. Thanks for the attempt anyway!

Comment: Well, to be honest, I think you've answered the question too quickly. The question is indeed somewhat unclear and involves mistakes at beginning, but that's not a reason for posting hasty answer. Leaving a comment asking for clarification is the better way to go, I think.

Comment: @xzczd Note that I answered another question that the author deleted. Should I delete my answer or put a question about deleting a post?

Comment: Yeah, that question is deleted because it turns out to be part of OP's mistake. Anyway, personally I think it's OK to keep this answer undeleted, solving differential-equation-related problem is arduous, and any answer that's not incorrect deserves upvote in my view. " …put a question about deleting a post?" Er… do you mean starting a post in meta? If so, I think it's not a bad idea.

Comment: Well, we leave everything as it is and continue the discussion. I will change my answer as soon as the result is obtained using  `pdetoode`.

Comment: Just see your update. The result given by `pdetoode` is _more_ reliable, if you add `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25, "MinPoints" -> 25, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}` to `sol1`, the result will be similar. The underlying issue is discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, really with additional options, the solutions are similar, although they do not match.