# Geometrically nonlinear beam deflection

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, physics, boundary-conditions

**Edit only for those interested in large deflections of beams**

I discovered a mistake in the equations of the original question (below): in the normal force (compression/traction) `n[s_] = EA*u1'[s];` the measure of stretch should not be `u1'`. The answers were very instructive in terms of numerical methods, nonetheless.

Actually, I thought the equations of beams under large deflections would be easy to derive as an ODE.  I now believe that in the general case, there is no simple explicit ODE to solve; instead the weak form can be projected directly on a mesh.

However, for thin beams undergoing mostly bending (no stretching), the problem can be solved pretty simply (the equations are nicely derived in "Large deflection states of Euler-Bernoulli slender cantilever beam subjected to combined loading" by Žiga Gosar and Franc Kosel, for instance). Numerically speaking, it seems to be much simpler to solve for the rotation field first, and then for the displacement field, rather than seeking the displacement field directly as I did below.

So, for those interested in large deflections of thin beam without stretching, these are some equations you could use:

```
(* Governing ODE for the rotations *)
eq = theta''[s] == q/EI*s*Cos[theta[s]] - (Q + q*L)/EI*Cos[theta[s]];
thetasol = First@NDSolveValue[{eq}~Join~{theta'[1] == 0, theta[0] == 0}, {theta}
     , {s, 0, L}];
(* Computation of the displacement field from the rotations *)
{xsol, ysol} = NDSolveValue[{x'[s] == Cos[thetasol[s]], y'[s] == Sin[thetasol[s]]
      , x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {s, 0, L}];
(* Plot of the deformed shape *)
ParametricPlot[{xsol[s], -ysol[s]}, {s, 0, L}, PlotRange -> Full
     , AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

**Now, back to the original question**

A lot of questions relate to solving the Euler-Bernoulli beam equation, mostly in dynamics. Actually, they mostly tackle the governing PDEs of the form $$\dfrac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} + \dfrac{\partial^4 w}{\partial w^4}=0$$
which corresponds to a *linearized* beam equation.

Here, I would like to find the shape of a clamped-free beam (for instance) with large deflection due to gravity; consider a sheet of paper with one clamped edge for example.

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187448/dynamic-nonlinear-damped-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation) also tries to address large deflection, but in my case, gravity couples axial and transverse displacements fields, plus I don't have a constraint on length.

So, let's write the equations in the local frame attached to the beam (`ft` for the force density in the tangential direction, `fn` for the force density in the normal direction):

```
eqs = {n'[s] - v[s]*kappa[s] + ft[s] == 0, (* local equilibrium, tang. direction *)
  v'[s] + n[s]*kappa[s] + fn[s] == 0, (* local equilibrium, transverse direction *)
  m'[s] + v[s] == 0} (* local equilibrium, moment *)
```

The beam, initially straight along the $x$ axis (between $x=0$ and $x=1$) has a deformed shape given by the parametric equation:
$$(s+u_1(s), u_2(s))$$

The corresponding curvature and local frame are given by:

```
{{kappa[s_]}, {tvec[s_], nvec[s_]}} = FrenetSerretSystem[{s + u1[s], u2[s]}, s];
```

Then, with Euler-Bernoulli kinematics, the internal tangential force field `n` and internal bending moment field `m` are given by:

```
EA = EI = 1000;
n[s_] = EA*u1'[s];
m[s_] = EI*kappa[s];
```

Then, the gravity is projected into the local frame:

```
gravity = {0, -10};
ft[s_] = gravity.tvec[s]
fn[s_] = gravity.nvec[s]
```

The third equation in `eqs` can be used to eliminate `v`:

```
v[s_] = v[s] /. (Solve[eqs[[3]], v[s]] // Last // Last) // Simplify;
eqs = eqs[[1 ;; 2]] // Simplify;
```

Along with the following boundary conditions ($u_1(0)=u_2(0)=0$, $u_2'(0)=0$ for the clamped end, $u_1''(1) = u_2''(1) = 0$, $u_1'(1) = 0$):

```
cls = {u1[0] == 0, u2[0] == 0, u2'[0] == 0, u1''[1] == 0, u2''[1] == 0, u1'[1] == 0}
```

Finally:

```
NDSolve[eqs~Join~cls, {u1, u2}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

returns two successive errors:

> NDSolve::ntdvdae: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. NDSolve will try solving the system as differential-algebraic equations.
>
> NDSolve::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems.

Any idea on how to solve this system?

**Note** It might be reasonable to neglect some terms (especially the squares of first derivatives) but `NDSolve` returns the same error.

xzczd suggested using his function [`pdftoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997) but I did not manage to make it work for my system of ODEs.

Comment: 1. It's better to include the system in this post, external link may be broken in future. 2. Have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871

Comment: @xzczd 1. Done. 2. Not very reassuring: `NDSolve` can't put the system in a first order form (`Solve` method), with `Residual` it can't solve BVPs, and it fails with `MassMatrix`. Should I understand that this can't be solved with _MMA_? I'm quite surprised (at least for the last one, which is rather simple).

Comment: If you can rewrite the system as 2nd order ODE system, then the `FiniteElement` method may be a choice. A more straightforward (at least for me) approach is FDM, this can be easily implemented with my [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).

Comment: @xzczd Do I need to introduce time to use `pdetoae`? Because I can't find a way of using your functions on my problem. Btw, the equations above (should) correspond to a Euler-Bernoulli beam deflection with large displacements (geometrically nonlinear), as in [187448](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187448/dynamic-nonlinear-damped-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation)---but in that question, I don't quite understand why the OP's equation are uncoupled...

Comment: @anderstood For gravity force of 10 it is better to use `EA = EI = 100` (for the realistic picture). Also `pdetoae`  is  a different tool then `pdetoode` I am used in my answer.

Comment: `u1''[1] == 0` is duplicated in `cls`.  What is the correct expression for `cls`?

Comment: As much as I understood you, the solution of the static version of the problem you formulated contains in the book Landau and Lifshitz, Theory of elasticity, Chapter II, §19, Problems 1-3. It is reformulated in terms of the nonlinear equation of the second order by passing from the displacement to the bending angle. The generalization to the dynamic case is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this system can be solved with `NDSolve` with some efforts. We use 3 equation:

```
eqs = {n'[s] - v[s]*kappa[s] + ft[s] == 0,
   v'[s] + n[s]*kappa[s] + fn[s] == 0,m'[s] + v[s] == 0};
{{kappa[s_]}, {tvec[s_], nvec[s_]}} = 
 FrenetSerretSystem[{s + u1[s], u2[s]}, s]; EA = 1000; EI = 1000;
n[s_] = EA*u1'[s];
m[s_] = EI*kappa[s]; gravity = {0, -10};
ft[s_] = gravity.tvec[s];
fn[s_] = gravity.nvec[s];
```

Now define function dependent on 3 parameters

```
solp[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{p1 = x, p2 = y, p3 = z}, 
   sol = NDSolve[
     Flatten[{eqs, {u1[0] == 0, u2[0] == 0, u2'[0] == 0, u1'[0] == p1,
         u2''[0] == p2, v[0] == p3}}], {u1, u2, v}, {s, 0, 1}, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]; sol[[1]]];
```

With this function we calculate initial data at `s=1`

```
U1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 u1''[1] /. solp[x, y, z]; 
U2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := u2''[1] /. solp[x, y, z];
 U3[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := u1'[1] /. solp[x, y, z]

init = {u1''[1], u2''[1], u1'[1]} /. solp[0, 0, 0];

solf = 
 FindRoot[{U1[x, y, z] == 0, U2[x, y, z] == 0, 
   U3[x, y, z] == 0}, {{x, init[[1]]}, {y, init[[2]]}, {z, init[[3]]}}]

(*Out[]= {x -> -7.52634*10^-10, y -> -0.00166661, z -> -6.66661}*)
```

Finally we visualize solution and compare with `pdetoae` solution

```
{Plot[Evaluate[u1[s] /. (solp[x, y, z] /. solf)], {s, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"s", "u1"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[u2[s] /. (solp[x, y, z] /. solf)], {s, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"s", "u2"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[v[s] /. (solp[x, y, z] /. solf)], {s, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"s", "v"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: In _v12.1.1_ the `solf` is `{x -> -7.52634*10^-10, y -> -0.00166661, z -> -6.66661}`, with these parameters I obtain the same solution as shown in my answer.

Comment: @xzczd Ah, sorry, it is my parameters were differ. Now corrected. Thank you!

Comment: It's interesting that retaining 3rd equation seems to be critical here.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, it leads to less order system of equations and it is easy with `NDSolve` to get right solution.

Comment: The idea of this answer is to relax the boundary conditions at `s = 1` and introduce instead more boundary conditions at `s=0` so that _Mathematica_ sees the problem as a initial value problem. Then, the extra initial values are adjusted so that the solution matches the desired boundary conditions at `s=1`. In short, it is a _shooting method_. The other answers are instructive too, though and it was hard to choose which one to accept.

Comment: @anderstood Thank you! After all redactions  we need to  change our answer too. Is not it?

Comment: @AlexTrounev No your answer addresses the OP. I think you do not need to change anything. But I wanted to add something to my question so that people who look for "large deflections of beam" do not find my wrong equations :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version
(* "12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)
```

`NDSolve` "cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives", because only one of the two ODEs is fourth order, as can be seen by determining the positions of `{u1''''[s], u2''''[s]}`.

```
Position[eqs, u1''''[s]]
(* {{2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2}} *)
Position[eqs, u2''''[s]]
(* {{2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2}} *)
```

Indeed, there are no fourth derivatives in eqs[[1]].  Nonetheless, some progress can be made.  For convenience, define

```
eq1 = Subtract @@ (eqs[[1]]);
eq2 = Subtract @@ (eqs[[2]]);
```

which moves all terms to the left side of the equations and then discards `== 0`.  Next, obtain the highest order derivatives in each expression.

```
eq1h = Simplify[Collect[eq1, {u1'''[s], u2'''[s]}, Simplify][[-2 ;; -1]]]
(* ((u2'[s]*u1''[s] - (1 + u1'[s])*u2''[s])*(u2'[s]*u1'''[s] - (1 + u1'[s])*u2'''[s]))
   /(1 + 2*u1'[s] + u1'[s]^2 + u2'[s]^2)^3 *)
eq2h = Simplify[Collect[eq2, {u1''''[s], u2''''[s]}, Simplify][[-2 ;; -1]]]
(* (u2'[s]*u1''''[s] - (1 + u1'[s])*u2''''[s])
   /(1 + 2*u1'[s] + u1'[s]^2 + u2'[s]^2)^(3/2) *)
```

The similarity of these two terms indicates that the fourth derivatives can be eliminated from `eq2`, as follows.

```
rat = Simplify[eq2h/eq1h (u2'[s] u1'''[s] - (1 + u1'[s]) u2'''[s])/
    (u2'[s] u1''''[s] - (1 + u1'[s]) u2''''[s])]
(* (1 + 2*u1'[s] + u1'[s]^2 + u2'[s]^2)^(3/2)/
   (u2'[s]*u1''[s] - (1 + u1'[s])*u2''[s]) *)
eq21 = Collect[eq2 - D[rat*eq1, s], {u1''''[s], u2''''[s]}, Simplify];
```

Although the resulting expression for `eq21` is too long to reproduce here, inspecting it using

```
{Coefficient[eq21, u1''''[s]], Coefficient[eq21, u2''''[s]]}
(* {0, 0} *)
```

verifies that the the fourth derivatives terms indeed are gone.  Moreover,

```
Flatten@Solve[{eq1 == 0, eq21 == 0}, {u1'''[s], u2'''[s]}]
```

gives explicit expressions for `{u1'''[s], u2'''[s]}`.  So, `NDSolve` can in principle integrate `{eq1 == 0, eq21 == 0}`.  To do so requires specifying six boundary conditions.  Presumably, `{u1'''[1] == 0, u2'''[1] == 0}` should be dropped from `cls`.  In addition, as noted in my comment, `u1''[1] == 0` is duplicated in `cls`.  Let us assume that the OP meant one of the duplicates to be `u2''[1] == 0`.  With these changes,

```
cls = {u1[0] == 0, u2[0] == 0, u2'[0] == 0, u1'[1] == 0, u2''[1] == 0, u1''[1] == 0}
```

At this point,

```
NDSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq21 == 0, cls}, {u1[s], u2[s]}, {s, 0, 1}]
```

runs for a while without error but eventually crashes as it searches for a boundary value solution.  Having a rough guess for the solution probably would yield an exact solution.

Comment: Mmh. On my MMA 12.1.1, `eq21` still has fourth order derivatives: `Position[eq21, u1''''[s]]` return `{{2, 4}}` for instance. And the `NDSolve` returns the same answer as in the OP, probably for that reason. I'll try to find what's wrong in the elimination of the 4th order terms.

Comment: Found a workaround: `eq21 = Collect[
   eq2 /. Solve[D[eq1, s] == 0, u1''''[s]], {u1''''[s], u2''''[s]}, 
   Simplify];`. Now `eq21` is a 3d-order ODE. I'll now investigate `NDSolve` which no longer returns the previous error. Thanks for the nice observation.

Comment: My outputs agree with yours up to `rat`, which is `-(1 + 2 Derivative[1][u1][s] + Derivative[1][u1][s]^2 + Derivative[1][u2][s]^2)^3` on my notebook. Maybe you multiplied the equations by the denominator? I get `eqs` by running the code from my answer. With `EA=EI=1` (which I changed in the OP), the equations should be: `eqs = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/hm1tcE6X"]`. Anyway, the point is that the fourth-order terms can be eliminated, now I have to wait for `NDSolve` to output something.

Comment: @anderstood  My expression for `rat` is precisely equal to `eq2h[[1]]/eq1h[[1 ;; 2]]`.  Perhaps, the order of terms in `eq1h` and `eq2h` differs between us.  I am using `$Version` 12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020).

Answer (score 3):

Let me add a solution based on finite difference method (FDM). I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equations.

```
domain = {0, 1}; points = 50; difforder = 8;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{u1, u2}[s], grid, difforder];
ae1 = ptoafunc@eqs[[1]] // Delete[#, {{1}, {2}, {-1}}] &;
ae2 = ptoafunc@eqs[[2]] // Delete[#, {{1}, {-2}, {-1}}] &;
aebc = cls // ptoafunc;
guess[_, x_] := 0
sollst = Partition[#, points] &@
   FindRoot[{ae1, ae2, aebc} // Flatten, 
     Table[{var[x], guess[var, x]}, {var, {u1, u2}}, {x, grid}] // 
      Flatten[#, 1] &][[All, -1]];

solfunclst = ListInterpolation[#, grid, InterpolationOrder -> difforder] & /@ sollst

ListLinePlot /@ sollst
```

[image]

Error check:

```
Subtract @@@ cls /. Thread[{u1, u2} -> solfunclst]
(* {2.06795*10^-23, 5.29396*10^-23, 9.7917*10^-19, 
    -7.22304*10^-15, -7.42942*10^-15, -1.96557*10^-17} *)
```

Comment: What equations and parameters do you use in your code?

Comment: @alex Those given in the question, of course.

Comment: Please, check my answer. The curves look similar but different in scale with yours. May be you take gravity as `{0,-1}`?