# Solving two coupled PDEs with the pdetoode function posted on this site

Tags: differential-equations, programming

I want to solve two coupled PDEs with [pdetoode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997) function:

```
feq = {D[ϕ, t] + U*D[ϕ, y] - D[ϕ, {y, 2}] - (s0 - 1/20*y^2)*ϕ == 0}
```

and

```
beq = {D[a, t] + U*D[a, y] + D[a, {y, 2}] + (s0 - 1/20*y^2)*a == 0}
```

To this end, I encapsulated them in the two solvers, which are very similar
(function `pdetoode` not included here, please find it from the above link):

```
feqSolver[s_, T_, g_] := Module[{s0 = s, Tend = T, feqIC = g},
  With[{ϕ = ϕ[t, y], U = y}, 
   feq = {D[ϕ, t] + U*D[ϕ, y] - 
       D[ϕ, {y, 2}] - (s0 - 1/20*y^2)*ϕ == 0};
   fic = {ϕ == feqIC[y]} /. t -> 0;
   fbc = {{ϕ == 0} /. y -> Ly, {ϕ == 0} /. y -> Uy};];
  fptoofunc = pdetoode[ϕ[t, y], t, grid, difforder];
  fdel = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
  fode = fdel@fptoofunc@feq[[1]];
  fodeic = fptoofunc@fic;
  fodebc = fptoofunc@fbc;
  fsollst = 
   NDSolveValue[{fodebc, fodeic, fode}, 
    Map[ϕ, grid], {t, 0, Tend}];
  fsol = ListInterpolation[
    Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ fsollst // 
     Transpose, {Flatten@fsollst[[1]]["Grid"], grid}];
  phisol[t_, y_] = ϕ[t, y] /. ϕ -> fsol[[1]];]

beqSolver[s_, T_, aT_] :=
 Module[{s0 = s, Tend = T, beqIC = aT},
  With[{a = a[t, y], U = y},
   beq = {D[a, t] + U*D[a, y] + D[a, {y, 2}] + (s0 - 1/20*y^2)*a == 0};
   bic = {a == beqIC[y]} /. t -> Tend;
   bbc = {{a == 0} /. y -> Ly, {a == 0} /. y -> Uy};];
  bptoofunc = pdetoode[a[t, y], t, grid, difforder];
  bdel = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
  bode = bdel@bptoofunc@beq[[1]];
  bodeic = bptoofunc@bic;
  bodebc = bptoofunc@bbc;
  bsollst = 
   NDSolveValue[{bodebc, bodeic, bode}, Map[a, grid], {t, Tend, 0}];
  bsol = ListInterpolation[
    Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ bsollst // 
     Transpose, {Flatten@bsollst[[1]]["Grid"], grid}];
  asol[t_, y_] = a[t, y] /. a -> bsol[[1]];]
```

Spatial domain and initial condition (IC):

```
Clear[g0, Ly, Uy]
Ly = -20; Uy = 20;
(*Giving a random IC for feq*)
SetAttributes[g0, Listable];
SeedRandom[1];
g0[y_?NumericQ] = 
  BSplineFunction[Join[{0.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 39], {0.}], 
    SplineClosed -> False][(y + 20)/40];
```

Define two functions: `J` is a function of interest, `aT` is a function used for constructing the IC for `beq`

```
Clear[J, aT];
J[g_, phiT_, y_] := 
  NIntegrate[Dot[g[y], g[y]], {y, Ly, Uy}]/
   NIntegrate[Dot[phiT[y], phiT[y]], {y, Ly, Uy}];
(*define how to generate IC for `beq` from the soln of `feq`*)
aT[g_, phiT_, 
   y_] := (-2*phiT[y]*
     NIntegrate[Dot[g[y], g[y]], {y, Ly, Uy}])/(NIntegrate[
      Dot[phiT[y], phiT[y]], {y, Ly, Uy}])^2;
```

Solve the two equation:

```
s0 = 0.4; Tend = 10;
g[y_?NumericQ] = g0[y];
phisol[t, y] = feqSolver[s0, Tend, g];
phiT[y] = phisol[Tend, y];
Jtest[[1]] = J[g, phiT, y]; (*evaluate a function of interest and save it as the first element of a list Jtest*)
aT[y] = aT[g, phiT, y];
asol[t, y] = beqSolver[s0, Tend, aT];
a0[y] = asol[0, y];
```

When run this code, MMA mainly gives this kind of error:

> Part::take: "Cannot take positions 2 through -2 in pdetoode[ϕ[t,y],t,grid,difforder]"
>   $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

By running the code line by line, I found that the first error results from `phisol[t, y] = feqSolver[s0, Tend, g];`

In the above code, I have used `Jtest[[1]]` since in my real problem I want to evaluate and save `Jtest[[iter]]` continuously (in a list) in a loop with an iterator `iter`. Then `Jtest[[iter]]` will be used for stopping the loop as follows:

```
Jtest[[iter]] = J[g, phiT, y]; AppendTo[Jtest, Jtest[[iter]]];
If[Abs[Jtest[[iter]] - Jtest[[iter - 1]]] < acc, Break[]];
```

**My problems are (1) should I define an empty list in the beginning, i.e. something like `Jtest={}`?; and (2) how do I fix these problems?

I have searched on the SE site for a similar problem but failed to solve it so far. And I have tried my best to learn the fundamental syntax of Mathematica for several months but I'm still in trouble. Please help and any suggestions and comments are very welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ……You still don't understand why `J[[iter]] = J[g, phiT, y];` doesn't make sense at all. Please consider asking a question about this, rather than immediately trying to deal with such a big problem. Also, recently I've written a relevant Chinese tutorial, please consider reading it: https://note.youdao.com/share/?id=f2cdd9e72b66c73f372296800de7f7f5&type=note#/

Comment: @user55777 Are you sure about this equation `beq = {D[a, t] + U*D[a, y] + D[a, {y, 2}] + (s0 - 1/20*y^2)*a == 0}` ? I ask about the sign `+ D[a, {y, 2}]`.

Comment: @xzczd can 'pdetoode' handle two coupled PDEs? the PDEs above are decoupled.

Comment: @S.Maths Of course. Notice `pdetoode`/`pdetoae` is just auxiliary tool for implementation of FDM, so it can of course handle PDE system, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184285/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/278430/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183745/1871 And you'll find more by searching `pdetoode`/`pdetoae` in this site.

Comment: @xzczd thanks. the 1st link is close to my case. I adapted accordingly but still got the error "There are more dependent variables..."

Answer (score 4):

I debugged the code for the first iteration.

```
Clear[fdd, pdetoode, tooderule]
fdd[{}, grid_, value_, order_, periodic_] := value;
fdd[a__] := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative@a;

pdetoode[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoode[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], 
   rest];
pdetoode[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoode[Alternatives[func][var], rest];
pdetoode[front__, grid_?VectorQ, o_Integer, periodic_: False] := 
  pdetoode[front, {grid}, o, periodic];

pdetoode[func_[var__], time_, {grid : {__} ..}, o_Integer, 
   periodic : True | False | {(True | False) ..} : False] := 
  With[{pos = Position[{var}, time][[1, 1]]}, 
   With[{bound = #[[{1, -1}]] & /@ {grid}, 
     pat = Repeated[_, {pos - 1}], 
     spacevar = Alternatives @@ Delete[{var}, pos]}, 
    With[{coordtoindex = 
       Function[coord, 
        MapThread[
         Piecewise[{{1, # === #2[[1]]}, {-1, # === #2[[-1]]}}, 
           All] &, {coord, bound}]]}, 
     tooderule@
      Flatten@{((u : func) | 
            Derivative[dx1 : pat, dt_, dx2___][(u : func)])[x1 : pat, 
          t_, x2___] :> (Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2};

          fdd[{dx1, dx2}, {grid}, 
           Outer[Derivative[dt][u@##]@t &, grid], 
           "DifferenceOrder" -> o, 
           PeriodicInterpolation -> periodic]), 
        inde : spacevar :> 
         With[{i = Position[spacevar, inde][[1, 1]]}, 
          Outer[Slot@i &, grid]]}]]];

tooderule[rule_][pde_List] := tooderule[rule] /@ pde;
tooderule[rule_]@Equal[a_, b_] := 
  Equal[tooderule[rule][a - b], 0] //. 
   eqn : HoldPattern@Equal[_, _] :> Thread@eqn;
tooderule[rule_][expr_] := #[[Sequence @@ #2[[1, 1]]]] & @@ 
  Reap[expr /. rule]
Clear@pdetoae;
pdetoae[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoae[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], rest];
pdetoae[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoae[Alternatives[func][var], rest];

pdetoae[func_[var__], rest__] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  Function[pde, #[
       pde /. {Derivative[d__][u : func][inde__] :> 
          Derivative[d, 0][u][inde, t], (u : func)[inde__] :> 
          u[inde, t]}] /. (u : func)[i__][t] :> u[i]] &@
   pdetoode[func[var, t], t, rest]]



g = Interpolation[
   Table[{-20 + i, If[1 < i < 40, RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0]}, {i, 0, 
     40}], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
s0 = 0.4; Tend = 10;

feq = {D[f[y, t], t] + y*D[f[y, t], y] - 
     D[f[y, t], {y, 2}] - (s0 - 1/20*y^2)*f[y, t] == 0};
fic = {f[y, 0] == g[y]};
fbc = {f[Ly, t] == 0, f[Uy, t] == 0};
points = 25;
difforder = 2;
{Ly, Uy} = domain = {-20, 20};
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
fptoofunc = pdetoode[f[y, t], t, grid, difforder];
fdel = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
fode = fdel /@ fptoofunc@feq;
fodeic = fdel /@ fptoofunc@fic;
fodebc = fbc // fptoofunc;
fsollst = 
  NDSolveValue[{fodebc, fodeic, fode}, 
   f /@ grid // Flatten, {t, 0, Tend}];
fsol = ListInterpolation[
   Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ fsollst // 
    Transpose, {Flatten@fsollst[[1]]["Grid"], grid}];


int1 = NIntegrate[g[y]^2, {y, Ly, Uy}];
int2 = NIntegrate[fsol[Tend, y], {y, Ly, Uy}];
h[y_] := -2*fsol[Tend, y]*int1/int2^2;
Jtest[1] = 
 int1/int2;(*evaluate a function of interest and save it as the first \
element of a list Jtest*)
Clear[f];
feq = {D[f[y, t], t] + y*D[f[y, t], y] + 
     D[f[y, t], {y, 2}] - (s0 - 1/20*y^2)*f[y, t] == 0};
fic = {f[y, 0] == h[y]};
fbc = {f[Ly, t] == 0, f[Uy, t] == 0};
points = 25;
difforder = 2;
{Ly, Uy} = domain = {-20, 20};
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
fptoofunc = pdetoode[f[y, t], t, grid, difforder];
fdel = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
fode = fdel /@ fptoofunc@feq;
fodeic = fdel /@ fptoofunc@fic;
fodebc = fbc // fptoofunc;
fsollst = 
  NDSolveValue[{fodebc, fodeic, fode}, 
   f /@ grid // Flatten, {t, 0, Tend}];
fsol1 = ListInterpolation[
   Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ fsollst // 
    Transpose, {Flatten@fsollst[[1]]["Grid"], grid}];

{Plot[g[y], {y, -20, 20}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "g"}], 
 Plot[h[y], {y, -20, 20}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "h"}], 
 ContourPlot[fsol[t, y], {t, 0, Tend}, {y, -20, 20}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "y"}, PlotLabel -> "\[Phi]"], 
 ContourPlot[fsol1[t, y], {t, 0, Tend}, {y, -20, 20}, Contours -> 20, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "y"}, PlotLabel -> "a"]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you. I just saw the answer. You didn't use `pdetoae`, so the related functions can be deleted.

Comment: @user55777 I just used your code in which I added parameters `grid, difforder` and correctly used  `pdetoode`. There is no reference to 'pdetoae' in your code.