# Solving linear coupled PDEs by FDM

Tags: differential-equations, finite-difference-method

I am trying to solve some linear, coupled PDEs for perturbative analysis (first order in time, 3rd order in space), for which I then plan to take the global spatial maxima of their magnitudes and plot them across time to show the temporal evolutions of the individual perturbations.

To solve the equations, I have attempted to use the template provided by user  [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183745/solve-pdes-with-finite-difference-scheme-by-modifying-ndsolve-based-solver).

```
p = .011;
ky = 10; 
c = 27;
Ω = 2800/p;
L = p/0.3; 
v = p^2* Ω/L;
A0 = 1;
xf=3;
Θ[x_] := -(3 c (1 + p^2 ky^2)/(2 p^2*v*ky)) (Sech[
      x c/(2 p*Sqrt[c^2 - ky^2 A0^2])]^2);

With[{A = A[t, x], Θ1 = Θ1[t, x], 
  vy = vy[t, x]},

 pde1 = D[
     A + p^2 (ky^2 A + 
         2 A0*Θ[x]*D[Θ1, x] - D[A, x, x]),
      t] - c*D[
      A + p^2 (ky^2 A + 
          2 A0*Θ[x]*D[Θ1, x] - 
          D[A, x, x]), x] + 
    p^2 (Θ[x])^2 (D[A, t] - 
       c*D[A, x]) == ((v p^2 ky)/(1 + (p^2 ky^2))) \
(2*(Θ[x])*D[A, x] + A0*D[Θ1, x, x]);


 pde2 = A0 (D[Θ1, t] - c*D[Θ1, x]) - 
    p^2 (D[Θ[x], x] (D[A, t] - c*D[A, x]) + 
       D[A0 D[Θ1, x, x] + 2 Θ[x] D[A, x], 
        t] - c*D[
         A0 D[Θ1, x, x] + 2 Θ[x] D[A, x], 
         x]) == ((v p^2 ky)/(1 + (p^2 ky^2))) (2 A0 Θ[
         x] D[Θ1, x] - D[A, x, x]) - 
    p^2 ky A0 D[vy, x, x];


 pde3 = (1/(p^4 Ω^2)) (D[vy, t] - c*D[vy, x]) == 
   ky A0^2 D[Θ1, x, x] + 
    D[2 ky A0 A Θ[x], x];]

pde = {pde1, pde2, pde3};

ic = {A[0, x] == 10^(-5), 
   vy[0, x] == 0, Θ1[0, x] == 0};


bc = {A[t, xf] == 0, (D[A[t, x], x] /. x -> xf) == 
    0, (D[A[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
    0, (D[Θ1[t, x], x] /. x -> xf) == 
    0, (D[Θ1[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
    0, Θ1[t, xf] == 0, 
   vy[t, xf] == 0, (D[vy[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0};

begintime = 0; endtime = 80;
points@x = 200; points@t = 25;
m = 200;
difforder = 8;
domain@x = {0, 3}; domain@t = {begintime, endtime};
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, t};


ptoafunc = 
  pdetoae[{A, Θ1, vy}[t, x], grid /@ {t, x}, 
   difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ae = Map[del, Most /@ ptoafunc@pde, {2}];
aeic = del /@ ptoafunc@ic;
aebc = ptoafunc@bc;
var = Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {A, Θ1, vy}, grid@t, grid@x];
{barray, marray} = 
   CoefficientArrays[Flatten@{ae, aeic, aebc}, 
    Flatten@var]; // AbsoluteTiming
Block[{p = .011,
    ky = 10,
    c = 27,
    Ω = 2800/p,
    L = p/0.3,
    v = p^2* Ω/L,
    A0 = 1}, 
   sollst = LinearSolve[N@marray, -barray]]; // AbsoluteTiming
solmatlst = ArrayReshape[sollst, var // Dimensions];
solfunclst = ListInterpolation[#, grid /@ {t, x}] & /@ solmatlst;
plot[f_, style_, t_] := 
 Plot[solfunclst[t, x] // Through // f // 
   Evaluate, {x, domain@x} // Flatten // Evaluate, 
  PlotStyle -> style]
```

but I run into an error once I run the code:

```
{17.5364, Null}
```

Could someone help resolve the error in this code? Or if I should be approaching this problem through different means? I apologize for the general inexperience in this matter. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where's the definition for `xf`?

Comment: @xzczd My bad, I forgot to include it here. xf should equal 3. I still seem to encounter some errors, however..

Comment: You've only given 5 b.c.s in the code (2 for `A`, 1 for `vy`, 2 for `\[CapitalTheta]1`), are you sure it's enough? _Usually_ the number of b.c. should be equal to the highest differential order in the corresponding direction for every unknown function.

Comment: @xzczd I had assumed the 3 initial conditions that I had provided for A, vy, and  \[CapitalTheta] had provided the rest of the conditions necessary (in total, 3 conditions for A, 3 for \[CapitalTheta] , and 2 for vy). My idea in defining these conditions was that a small perturbation in A would saturate the other two fields (Theta, vy), and at xf, the perturbations should disappear. Should I add two more b.c. for the general system?

Comment: Notice _usually_ the number of i.c./b.c. should be equal to the highest differential order in **corresponding direction** for every unknown function i.e. you need 3 i.c.s and 8 b.c.s in total.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much for that info. I have updated the b.c. and the value of xf in the main text accordingly.

Comment: You're not removing redundant equations properly. For $n$ unknown variables, we need $n$ independent equations to form a close system. Check `ptoafunc@pde // Dimensions` and `ptoafunc@bc // Dimensions` and think about which part of the system should be removed.

Comment: After second look at the PDE system, I find the highest differential order of `[\[CapitalTheta]1` respect to `x` is `2` rather than `3`, is it correct?

Comment: @xzczd The highest order of  [\[CapitalTheta]1 is 3, I believe, from the first time of this line in pde2: c*D[
         A0 D[\[CapitalTheta][x], x, x] + 
          2 \[CapitalTheta][x] D[A[t, x], x], 
         x])

Comment: @xzczd I have looked at ptoafunc@pde // Dimensions and ptoafunc@bc // Dimensions, and they return {3, 25, 200} and {8, 25}. Would I be right in that since I have 8 b.c., I need to get rid of 8 equations from each pde and ic that I have? If so, how would I go about modifying the code to do this? Specifically, I'm having a little trouble deciphering the results from ptoafunc@pde // Dimensions and ptoafunc@bc // Dimensions and how I would modify del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &; for this.

Comment: ……It's `\[CapitalTheta]` rather than `\[CapitalTheta]1`.

Comment: @xzczd Sorry, it was supposed to be a \[CapitalTheta]1. I've checked all my equations again so that I haven't made any more typos and updated the main body. I'm truly sorry about that.

Comment: @xzczd I also ran ptoafunc@pde // Dimensions and ptoafunc@bc // Dimensions, which gave {3, 25, 200} and {8, 25} respectively. Is my general understanding that since I have 8 b.c., I must get rid of 8 equations for my pdes and i.c.'s? I'm a little confused on how to interpret the above results, and how to update del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &; accordingly. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: You still have `\[CapitalTheta]1[x]` in your code. I suggest using `With` as shown in e.g. [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180109/1871) to simplify your code so it'll be easier to check.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! It's much more tractable now.

Comment: As to the removing of redundant equations, since you have `3×25×200` unknown variables to solve, while `3×25×200 + 3×200 + 8×25` equations at hand, you need to remove `3×200 + 8×25` from the system. But are you sure now the system is correct? I've tried various settings for `points`, `difforder`, etc., but the solution always becomes unstable very fast.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I have just confirmed that the system is correct. Although, the overarching plan was to test at regimes near M=c/(kyA0) ->1 (like in this example) and away from it, since the base state (\[CapitalTheta]) has an approximate  resonance near c ~kyA0. Since my pde's are normalized, my plan was to leave A0 as 1 and manipulate c and ky to see how stable this base state was as c>>ky and c~ky. And thank you very much for your answer on the question about how to approach the redundancy!

Comment: OK, I didn't notice the removing in `t` dimension is also wrong. Now the code gives reasonable result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, let me extend my comments to an answer. Your code doesn't give proper result because you haven't removed the redundant equations properly.

First of all, notice [`pdetoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) will discretize equations in the following way:

1. If the equation is defined on the whole domain of definition, difference equations will be generated on every grid points. In your case, you'll obtain `3 × points[t] × points[x]` difference equations after discretizing the 3 PDEs.
2. If the equation is only defined on the boundary of the domain of definition, difference equations will only be generated on grid points on the boundary. In your case, you'll obtain `3 × points[x]` equations after discretizing i.c.s, and `8 × points[t]` equations after discretizing b.c.s.

Now here comes the problem, we only have `3 × points[t] × points[x]` unknown variables in the discretized system, but `3 × points[t] × points[x] + 3 × points[x] + 8 × points[t]` equations, so the system is over-determined and we need to remove some of the equations as redundant ones. Which ones should be removed? Those closest to the i.c.s and b.c.s. (But why? Honestly speaking, I don't know, but this strategy seems to always work well. )

The following is the fixed code. I've reduced `endtime` to `1/2` because the solution damps fast.

```
p = 0.011; ky = 10; c = 27; Ω = 2800/p; L = p/0.3; v = (p^2 Ω)/L; A0 = 1; xf = 3;
Θ[x_] := -(((3 c (1 + p^2 ky^2)) Sech[(x c)/(2 p Sqrt[c^2 - ky^2 A0^2])]^2)/(
   2 p^2 v ky));
Clear[pde, ae, aeic]
With[{A = A[t, x], Θ1 = Θ1[t, x], vy = vy[t, x]}, 
 pde@1 = D[A + 
      p^2 (ky^2 A + 2 A0*Θ[x]*D[Θ1, x] - D[A, x, x]), t] - 
    c*D[A + p^2 (ky^2 A + 2 A0*Θ[x]*D[Θ1, x] - D[A, x, x]), 
      x] + p^2 (Θ[x])^2 (D[A, t] - 
       c*D[A, x]) == ((v p^2 ky)/(1 + (p^2 ky^2))) (2*(Θ[x])*D[A, x] + 
      A0*D[Θ1, x, x]);

 pde@2 = A0 (D[Θ1, t] - c*D[Θ1, x]) - 
    p^2 (D[Θ[x], x] (D[A, t] - c*D[A, x]) + 
       D[A0 D[Θ1, x, x] + 2 Θ[x] D[A, x], t] - 
       c*D[A0 D[Θ1, x, x] + 2 Θ[x] D[A, x], 
         x]) == ((v p^2 ky)/(1 + (p^2 ky^2))) (2 A0 Θ[
         x] D[Θ1, x] - D[A, x, x]) - p^2 ky A0 D[vy, x, x];

 pde@3 = (1/(p^4 Ω^2)) (D[vy, t] - c*D[vy, x]) == 
   ky A0^2 D[Θ1, x, x] + D[2 ky A0 A Θ[x], x];
 ic = {A == 1/10^5, Θ1 == 0, vy == 0} /. t -> 0; 
 bc = {{A == 0, D[A, x] == 0, D[Θ1, x] == 0, Θ1 == 0, 
      vy == 0} /. x -> xf, {D[A, x] == 0, D[Θ1, x] == 0, 
     D[vy, x] == 0}} /. x -> 0;]

begintime = 0; endtime = 1/2(*1/10*);
points@x = 200; points@t = 25;
difforder = 4;
domain@x = {0, xf}; domain@t = {begintime, endtime};
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, t};

(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{A, Θ1, vy}[t, x], grid /@ {t, x}, difforder];
deletetwo = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
deletethree = #[[2 ;; -3]] &;
{ae@1, ae@2} = deletethree /@ Rest@ptoafunc@pde@# & /@ {1, 2};
{ae@3} = deletetwo /@ Rest@ptoafunc@pde@# & /@ {3};
{aeic@1, aeic@2} = deletethree@ptoafunc@ic[[#]] & /@ {1, 2};
{aeic@3} = deletetwo@ptoafunc@ic[[#]] & /@ {3};
aebc = ptoafunc@bc;
var = Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {A, Θ1, vy}, grid@t, grid@x];
{barray, marray} = 
   CoefficientArrays[Flatten@{ae /@ {1, 2, 3}, aeic /@ {1, 2, 3}, aebc}, 
    Flatten@var]; // AbsoluteTiming

sollst = LinearSolve[N@marray, -barray]; // AbsoluteTiming

solmatlst = ArrayReshape[sollst, var // Dimensions];
solfunclst = ListInterpolation[#, grid /@ {t, x}] & /@ solmatlst;

GraphicsRow[(Plot3D[#1[t, x], {t, begintime, endtime}, {x, 0, xf}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotPoints -> 50] &) /@ solfunclst]
```

[image]

You may need to adjust `difforder`, `points`, etc. further to obtain an accurate enough result.

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much, I really can't appreciate your help and patience enough!

Comment: @user213068 Glad it helps. Actually you don't need to accept that fast, it's OK to wait for a while to see if someone comes with a better answer.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the standard solver with special options. The pictures are not as beautiful as using `pdetoae`, but perhaps other solutions have been found here.

```
p = .011;
ky = 10;
c = 27;
\[CapitalOmega] = 2800/p;
L = p/0.3;
v = p^2*\[CapitalOmega]/L;
A0 = 1;
xf = 3;
\[CapitalTheta][
   x_] := -(3 c (1 + p^2 ky^2)/(2 p^2*v*ky)) (Sech[
      x c/(2 p*Sqrt[c^2 - ky^2 A0^2])]^2);

With[{A = A[t, x], \[CapitalTheta]1 = \[CapitalTheta]1[t, x], 
  vy = vy[t, x]}, 
 pde1 = D[A + 
      p^2 (ky^2 A + 2 A0*\[CapitalTheta][x]*D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x] - 
         D[A, x, x]), t] - 
    c*D[A + p^2 (ky^2 A + 
          2 A0*\[CapitalTheta][x]*D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x] - 
          D[A, x, x]), x] + 
    p^2 (\[CapitalTheta][x])^2 (D[A, t] - 
       c*D[A, x]) == ((v p^2 ky)/(1 + (p^2 ky^2))) \
(2*(\[CapitalTheta][x])*D[A, x] + A0*D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x, x]);
 pde2 = A0 (D[\[CapitalTheta]1, t] - c*D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x]) - 
    p^2 (D[\[CapitalTheta][x], x] (D[A, t] - c*D[A, x]) + 
       D[A0 D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x, x] + 2 \[CapitalTheta][x] D[A, x], 
        t] - 
       c*D[A0 D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x, x] + 
          2 \[CapitalTheta][x] D[A, x], 
         x]) == ((v p^2 ky)/(1 + (p^2 ky^2))) (2 A0 \[CapitalTheta][
         x] D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x] - D[A, x, x]) - 
    p^2 ky A0 D[vy, x, x];
 pde3 = (1/(p^4 \[CapitalOmega]^2)) (D[vy, t] - c*D[vy, x]) == 
   ky A0^2 D[\[CapitalTheta]1, x, x] + 
    D[2 ky A0 A \[CapitalTheta][x], x];]

pde = {pde1, pde2, pde3};

ic = {A[0, x] == 10^(-5), vy[0, x] == 0, \[CapitalTheta]1[0, x] == 0};


bc = {A[t, xf] == 0, (D[A[t, x], x] /. x -> xf) == 
    0, (D[A[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
    0, (D[\[CapitalTheta]1[t, x], x] /. x -> xf) == 
    0, (D[\[CapitalTheta]1[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
    0, \[CapitalTheta]1[t, xf] == 0, 
   vy[t, xf] == 0, (D[vy[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0};

{as, vs, tets} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, bc}, {A, vy, \[CapitalTheta]1}, {t, 0, 
    1}, {x, 0, xf}, 
   Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
     "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
     "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 30, "MaxPoints" -> 30}}}];

{Plot3D[as[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, xf}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}, 
  PlotLabel -> "A", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[vs[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, xf}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}, 
  PlotLabel -> "vy", PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue], 
 Plot3D[tets[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, xf}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", ""}, PlotLabel -> "\[CapitalTheta]1", 
  PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Interesting. Just a side note: this solution won't work in _v9.0.1_, but works at least in _v11.2_ and _v12_. BTW, my solution isn't necessarily the better one, actually it varies quite a bit if `points[t]` becomes larger…

Comment: @xzczd Therefore, I have placed this code so that it can be seen that with the automatic selection of the integration step in `t` there may be other modes.

Comment: @xzczd , Alex I actually had a question about the dependence of t with these methods of FDM. I was testing c=20.01, ky=20 and found that, while for large endtime (w. xzczd's algorithm), the solutions decayed very fast (endtime ~3),  changing the endtime to zoom into this solution gives weird flaps for all the plots towards endtime (~0.2). I ran Alex's code for these parameters, but it returns a "scaled local spatial error estimate.. in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance." Is there a reason for these behaviours? Thanks so much

Comment: @AlexTrounev And thank you so much for your response! It's very helpful in learning the ways these methods may be employed.

Comment: @user213068 The `eerr` warning returns by Alex's solution indicates `NDSolve` _thinks_ the obtained solution isn't accurate enough. As to the behavior of my solution, sadly stability analysis for certain finite difference scheme is beyond my (and most average user's, I'm afraid) reach and I don't have any theoretical explanation, judging whether the solution is reliable enough based on the physical background and by testing various parameters is the most practical way to go, I think.

Comment: @xzczd Ah I see, thank you for your response nonetheless. I was also thinking similarly— since these anomalies only appear at whatever small endtime I assign but don’t appear otherwise at the same points for a relatively larger (but still small, ~0.2) endtime, I concluded that they must be due to the finite scheme rather than the actual dynamics of the system. For very large endtimes (~3,80), such anomalies disappear and the solutions all decay smoothly w similar structures. (Also general sidenote: xf was changed from 3 to 0.1 for this simulation if anyone wanted to know/see this behaviour).

Comment: @user213068 What does this solution to a system of equations describe?

Comment: @Alex Perturbations for a wave’s amplitude, phase and a flow that is generated by the inhomogeneities of the amplitude and phase .The system (Hasegawa Mima) was decomposed from two coupled equations for the wave and flow, and is known to be stable without external forcing. For our purposes, we set A = const (A0 in code) to find out what a dynamic phase contributes to the system rather than assume eikonal form, and we derived base states analytically. In my code, Theta corresponds to the base phase gradient (although Theta 1 is the perturbation of the phase, not its gradient).

Comment: @user213068 In practice, should we get something like turbulence?

Comment: @Alex Trounev Without external forcing, no. Turbulence is intrinsic for the more general Hasegawa Wakatani. That being said, since the phase is usually treated in eikonal form, I wasn’t sure what to expect for the stability of the phase, or the stability of A in regards to a base state of const amplitude (the limit was only enforced to isolate phase dynamics in a minimal model). For xf very large (3000), NDSolve ran fine given some commands like PDEdiscretization etc, and showed stability for both c>> ky and c~ky, but once I made the correction to xf to 3, NDS would fail.

Comment: @Alex Trounev But this stability, as well as the reasons I’ve stated in my previous comment, are why I’m inclined to believe that the states are indeed stable.

Comment: @user213068 Why don't you directly solve the Hasegawa-Mima equation in 2D? Your system of equations looks more complicated and it is not clear what it describes.