# Help with solving a PDE and plotting its solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I have trouble with solving the PDE with periodic boundary condition, which appears to be stiff somewhere, so I tried `"StiffnessSwitching"`. But the code still doesn't work.

```
k = 3/100; L = 2*Pi; tm = 4;
usol = First[u /.NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] + 
   D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + k*D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] == 0,
 u[0, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == -Sin[x]}, 
u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tm}, 
Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> Automatic}, 
MaxSteps -> \[Infinity](*,
AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 20*)]]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.7462410870827023`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

Here, I also used a sub-method `"NonstiffTest" -> Automatic`, which **allows the `Method` to switch back from a stiff to a nonstiff method to save time and for better flexibility** (if it is the case with `Automatic`, I am not sure.). Even though I went through [Stiffness Detection](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStiffnessTest.html), I have no idea which option is appropriate for the problem: `False`, `"NormBound"`, `"Direct"`, `SubspaceIteration`, `"KrylovIteration"`, `Automatic`. So I just used `Automatic` for more flexible. (Am I right?)

**Problems:**

1. Assuming the equation has been solved, and how to plot a function `f[t]` of the solution `u[x,t]`: `f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[usol[x, t]^2, {x, 0, L}]`, in this fashion

   ```
   ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{f[t], f'[t]}], {t, 0, tm}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
   ```
2. In addition, if I added `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 20` in `NDSolve`, the code gives another warning instead

   > Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.

Why is that? I do not understand the error, because the initial condition and bounary condition are given.

Any comment is very welcome.

Comment: Are you sure you were right about the signs in the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, this problem has a solution with v.12.

```
k = 3/100; L = 2*Pi; tm = 4;
usol = First[
  u /. NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] + 
       D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + k*D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] == 0, 
     u[0, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == -Sin[x]}, 
    u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tm}, 
    Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
      "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> 237, "MaxPoints" -> 237}}}]]
Plot3D[usol[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tm}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We use Gaussian quadrature  to integrate and interpolation (Problem 1):

```
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
np = 63; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[
 points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 2*Pi][[i, 1]], {i, 1, 
  np}]
Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 2*Pi][[i, 2]], {i, 
  1, np}]
GaussInt[f_, z_] := 
 Sum[(f /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]

ff = Table[{t, GaussInt[usol[x, t]^2, x]}, {t, 0, tm, .05}];

fint = Interpolation[ff]
Plot[fint[t], {t, 0, tm}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "f"}]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{fint[t], fint'[t]}], {t, 0, tm}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Code for version 9. All inputs are the same, but the output is slightly different (another method?).

```
k = 3/100; L = 2*Pi; tm = 4;
usol = First[
  u /. NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] + 
       D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + k*D[u[x, t], {x, 4}] == 0, 
     u[0, t] == u[L, t], u[x, 0] == -Sin[x]}, 
    u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tm}, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> 333}}}]]
Plot3D[usol[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tm}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue]
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
np = 63; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[
 points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 2*Pi][[i, 1]], {i, 1, 
  np}]
Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 2*Pi][[i, 2]], {i, 
  1, np}]
GaussInt[f_, z_] := 
 Sum[(f /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]
ff = Table[{t, GaussInt[usol[x, t]^2, x]}, {t, 0, tm, .05}];
fint = Interpolation[ff]
Plot[fint[t], {t, 0, tm}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "f"}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{fint[t], fint'[t]}], {t, 0, tm}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thanks @Alex Trounev, but I have v.9 only. I am wondering how did find the appropriate combination of options for `NDSolve` as well as the number for `Min/MaxPoints`?  With `Residual`, does it imply that the PDE is treated as a DAE?

Comment: @Enter I'll see what can be used in version 9. Try to use  `pdetoae` as in this example https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199385/solving-linear-coupled-pdes-by-fdm/199470#199470

Comment: @Enter I found options for version 9. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But it was found that `PDEDiscritization` in *not* necessary. With `Method -> {"MethodOfLines",  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 333}}`, one got the same result. In addition, if I added a `DifferenceOrder` option for `"SpatialDiscretization"` in order to make the method more transparent, it seems to take a longer time. Any idea?

Comment: @Enter Use `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 41, 
    "MaxPoints" -> 101, 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}`

Comment: @Enter This is a purely empirical set of options that I used to solve this problem.

Comment: @Enter From tutorial "`GaussianQuadratureWeights[n,a,b]`
gives a list of the n pairs `{Subscript[x, i],Subscript[w, i]}` of the elementary n-point Gaussian formula for quadrature on the interval a to b, where `Subscript[w, i]` is the weight of the abscissa `Subscript[x, i]`."

Comment: @AlexTounev I found your code for Gaussian quadrature runs sooo slow in v11.3, do you have any suggestion to speed it up?

Comment: @Enter We can use `np = 63; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 2*Pi]; {points, 
  weights} = {g[[All, 1]], g[[All, 2]]}` instead of `np = 63; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; Do[points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 2*Pi][[i, 1]], {i, 1, np}]; Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, 0, 2*Pi][[i, 2]], {i,1, np}];`

Comment: @AlexTounev Thanks you. But the change does not speed up too much. I am working on another problem with Gaussian quadrature, even using `ParallelTable`, it is still so slow.

Comment: @Enter Sorry, I have no v11.3 to test code.  With current v12.3 this code is very fast.