# Unable to implement boundary conditions for a spherical wave equation coupled to a Laplace equation

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am having trouble setting up in Mathematica v 12.1 the following
system of coupled pdes on $r\in[0,10]$
$$ \left(\partial_t^2 - \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r r^2 \partial_r \right) \theta(t,r) = -(1+2\Phi(t,r))\theta(t,r)$$
$$\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r r^2 \partial_r \Phi(t,r) = \theta(t,r)^2  $$
For $\theta$ I have the initial conditions
$$\theta(0,r)=e^{-r^2}, \qquad \partial_t\theta(0,r)=0.$$
and smoothness bc at origin and absorbing bc at $r=10$.
$$\partial_r \theta(t,0)=0, \qquad \left.\partial_t(r \theta(t,r))\right|_{r=10}+\left.\partial_r(r \theta(t,r))\right|_{r=10}=0$$
The latter ensures no information comes in from outside the domain.
$\Phi$ can be obtained by integrating the second equation so I don't believe I need to provide initial conditions for it. There are in principle two integration constants however so I must therefore impose two conditions, e.g.
$$\partial_r \Phi(t,0)=0, \qquad \Phi(t,0)=-4$$

Below is how I've tried to implement it in Mathematica. (As far as I understand, the smoothness bc at the origin are taken care of automatically). I get the following error

[image]

```
tend = 100.;
rstart = 1/10^100;
rend = 10;

ic = {\[Theta][0, r] == Exp[-(r)^2], (D[\[Theta][t, r], t] /. t -> 0) == 0};
bc = {\[CapitalPhi][t, 0] == -4};

{teta, phi} = NDSolveValue[Flatten@{-((2 r \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\),TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}],")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, r] + r^2\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, r])/r^2) +\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t,r] == -(1 + 2 \[CapitalPhi][t, r]) \[Theta][t, r] + NeumannValue[-Derivative[1, 0][\[Theta]][t, r] - \[Theta][t, r]/r, r == rend] , ((2 r \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalPhi]\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(",RowBox[{"0",",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, r] + r^2 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalPhi]\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "2"}],")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, r])/r^2) == \[Theta][t, r]^2, ic,bc}, {\[Theta], \[CapitalPhi]}, {t, 0, tend}, {r, rstart, rend}]

Animate[Plot[{teta[t, r], phi[t, r]}, {r, 0, rend},PlotRange -> {{0, rend}, {-1, 1}}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

Comment: Look at the boundary condition: `bc = {\[CapitalPhi][t, r] == -4}` This is an equation for phi that determines phi and not a boundary condition.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHuber, that was an unfortunate typo, I've edited my question to restrict myself to the main error message

Comment: @xzczd fixed, thanks

Comment: Well, PDE system that involves equation doesn't explicitly involves pure derivative of `t` is troublesome, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184285/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163956/1871 But, are you sure the system itself is correct? I just tried solving it with FDM, but the resulting discretized system seems to be ill-conditioned.