# ComplexExpand no longer assumes Derivative[__][__][__] as real

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, complex

**Bug introduced after 12.0.1, in or before 12.3, persisting through 13.0. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

Consider the following sample:

```
{Re, Im}[u'[t]] // Through // ComplexExpand
```

In *v9.0.1* `u'[t]` is assumed as real:

[image]

But at least since *v12.3.1* the behavior changes:

[image]

Is this a bug or incompatible change?

Is there a simple way to bring back the old behavior? ([This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163956/1871) of mine is broken at the moment due to the change. )

Comment: The docs indicate no update to `ComplexExpand` since V6.0, so you should report it.

Comment: I get the first (desired) result on 11.3.0 for Mac OS X.

Comment: Possible workaround: `Activate@ComplexExpand[{Re, Im}[Inactivate[u'[t]]] // Through]`

Comment: A workaround: `Simplify[{Re, Im}[u'[t]] // Through, u'[t] \[Element] Reals]`. Or, to have the assumptions persist and just use `Simplify`: `$Assumptions = $Assumptions && u'[t] \[Element] Reals; {Re, Im}[u'[t]] // Through // Simplify`

Comment: Filing a bug report for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments have identified this as a bug; in the meantime, a simple way to bring back the old behavior for `ComplexExpand` in a given session can be obtained by adding the following definition to `ComplexExpand`. This builds on Michael E2's (in)activation workaround; I noticed that it really is just the `Derivative` symbol itself that gives us grief, so we can restrict our inactivation to `Derivative` per se.

```
Unprotect[complexExpandIntercept, ComplexExpand];
complexExpandIntercept = True;
ComplexExpand[args___] := 
 Block[{complexExpandIntercept = False}, 
   Activate[
    ComplexExpand @@ Inactivate[{args}, Derivative], 
    Derivative]] /; complexExpandIntercept
Protect[complexExpandIntercept, ComplexExpand];
```

```
{Re, Im}[u'[t]] // Through // ComplexExpand

(* Out: {Derivative[1][u][t], 0} *)
```

Note: for a brief moment this answer was incorrect due to flipped booleans; now it should be fixed. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here another workaround that may be safe (as it would likely affect only expressions containing `u'`):

```
ComplexExpand[Null]; (* autoload ComplexExpandDump *)
Block[{System`ComplexExpandDump`ConjugateFunctions = 
   Append[System`ComplexExpandDump`ConjugateFunctions, u']},
 ComplexExpand[{Re, Im}[u'[t]] // Through]]
(*  {u'[t], 0}  *)
```

Comment: I think you mean `ComplexExpand[u'[t] // Re]` :) ? Then, it seems that we need to use `ComplexExpand` at least once before using the solution, otherwise ``System`ComplexExpandDump`ConjugateFunctions`` won't be loaded.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! (It turns out internally it complex-expands the real and imaginary parts of `u'[t]` anyway, so that at some point I dropped the `Re` and `Im`.)