# Why does NDSolve fail to solve the PDEs and spit out mconly warning?

Tags: differential-equations

I try to solve two coupled PDEs with `NDSolve` using the following code:

1. Set two operators:

   ```
   op1[y_, α_, β_] = ((α^2 + β^2)*# - D[#, {y, 2}]) &;
   op2[y_, α_, β_] = (op1[y, α, β]@ op1[y, α, β]@#) &;
   ```
2. Set the parameters:

   ```
   α = 1; β = 0.5; m = 300; Tend = 20; nx = 201;
   ```
3. Set the equation, boundary and initial conditions (BCs and ICs):

   ```
   With[{η = η[t, y], v = v[t, y], U = 1 - y^2},
    feq = {D[η, t] + I*α*U*η + 
    1/m*op1[y, α, β][η] == -I*β*D[U, y]*v,
   op1[y, α, β][D[v, t]] + 
    I*α*U*op1[y, α, β][v] + 
    I*α*D[U, {y, 2}]*v + 1/m*op2[y, α, β][v] == 0};
   fic = {η == η0[y], v == v0[y]} /. t -> 0;
   fbc = {{v == 0, η == 0, D[v, y] == 0} /. y -> -1,
   {v == 0, η == 0, D[v, y] == 0} /. y -> 1};]
   ```
4. Take random (smooth) functions as the ICs (In my real problem, I need random values of the functions to initiate the numerical integration in `NDSolve`):

   ```
   SeedRandom[1];
   η0[y_] = BSplineFunction[Join[{0.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], {0.}], SplineClosed -> False][(y + 1)/2];
   SeedRandom[2];
   v0[y_] = BSplineFunction[Join[{0.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], {0.}], SplineClosed -> False][(y + 1)/2];
   ```
5. Solve the system:

   ```
   fsol = NDSolve[{feq, fic, fbc}, {η, v}, {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, Tend},
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MinPoints" -> nx, "MaxPoints" -> nx, "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
   ```

The code has been run in Mathematica V9.0, which gives the following warnings:

> NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. >>

This error is understandable because the ICs are two random functions, although I managed to satisfy $v(\pm1,t)=\eta(\pm,t)=0$, the remaining $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(\pm1,t)=0$ have not in general. But I guess this warning is not a big deal.

> NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions. >>

Why NDSolve is unable to deal with complex values? I do need complex numbers in the numerical solutions.

> NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.

This error should be the most important one but I cannot understand this issue.

6. If the PDEs could be solved, I want to plot:

   ```
   u1[t, y] = I/α*D[v[t, y], y] /. fsol[[1]];
   u3[t, y] = I/α*η[t, y] /. fsol[[1]];
   ```

Please help me. Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: From your code it is not clear what problem you want to solve? Write the equation and boundary conditions.

Comment: @alex It's `{feq, fic, fbc}`, isn't it?

Comment: @xzczd After your solving the problem, it became clear what problem is being solved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Explanation for the Warning

Notice the description for the warning `NDSolve::mconly` is

> NDSolve::mconly: **For the method IDA**, only machine real code is available.

What's method IDA? It's a method for solving DAE. (Please search in the document for more information. )

Why is `NDSolve` calling a DAE solver? Because `NDSolve` discretizes the PDE system based on method of lines (`"MethodOfLines"`) and the resulting system is a DAE system or an ODE system.

Why does `NDSolve` choose to discretize the PDE system to a DAE system rather than an ODE system? Because your PDE system involves terms like $\frac{\partial ^2v}{\partial t\partial y}$ and current implementation of method of lines in `NDSolve` isn't clever enough to transform the discretized system to the standard form required by the ODE solver. (For more information about the standard form, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871). )

Why does the DAE solver fail? Because generally the DAE solver of *Mathematica* is weaker than the ODE solver, at least up to now.

## Solutions

### Partly `NDSolve`-based solution

One possible method to resolve the problem is to discretize the system ourselves and help `NDSolve` to use the ODE solver as I've done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163956/1871). I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task.

Notice I've modified the definition of `η0` and `v0` a little, because `pdetoode` can only handle `Listable` function.

```
(* Tested in v9.0.1 *)
Clear[η0, v0, α, β]

op1[y_, α_, β_] = ((α^2 + β^2)*# - D[#, {y, 2}]) &;
op2[y_, α_, β_] = (op1[y, α, β]@ op1[y, α, β]@#) &;

SetAttributes[#, Listable] & /@ {η0, v0};
SeedRandom[1];
η0[y_?NumericQ] = 
  BSplineFunction[Join[{0.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], {0.}], 
    SplineClosed -> False][(y + 1)/2];
SeedRandom[2];
v0[y_?NumericQ] = 
  BSplineFunction[Join[{0.}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], {0.}], 
    SplineClosed -> False][(y + 1)/2];

α = 1; β = 0.5; m = 300; Tend = 20; nx = 201;

With[{η = η[t, y], v = v[t, y], U = 1 - y^2}, 
   feq = {D[η, t] + I α U η + op1[y, α, β][η]/m == (-I) β D[U, y] v, 
          op1[y, α, β][D[v, t]] + 
            I α U op1[y, α, β][v] + I α D[U, {y, 2}] v + op2[y, α, β][v]/m == 0}; 
 fic = {η == η0[y], v == v0[y]} /. t -> 0; 
 fbc = {{v == 0, η == 0, D[v, y] == 0} /. y -> -1, 
        {v == 0, η == 0, D[v, y] == 0} /. y -> 1}; ]

domain = {-1, 1};
difforder = 2;
points = 50;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[{η, v}[t, y], t, grid, difforder];

delone = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
deltwo = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;

ode@1 = delone@ptoofunc@feq[[1]];
ode@2 = deltwo@ptoofunc@feq[[2]];
odeic = ptoofunc@fic;
odebc = ptoofunc@With[{sf = 1}, diffbc[t, sf]@fbc];
var = Outer[#[#2] &, {η, v}, grid];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode /@ {1, 2}, odeic, odebc}, var, {t, 0, Tend}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"}];

fsol = rebuild[#, grid]& /@ sollst;

Clear[u1, u3]    
u1[t_, y_] = I/α D[v[t, y], y] /. v -> fsol[[2]];
u3[t_, y_] = I/α η[t, y] /. η -> fsol[[1]];

Plot3D[u1[t, y] // Abs // Evaluate, {t, 0, Tend}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[u3[t, y] // Abs // Evaluate, {t, 0, Tend}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may try larger `difforder` or `points`.

If you want to make the solution fit the b.c. better, choose a larger `sf`. As to the meaning of `sf`, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

### Purely FDM-based solution

<strike>As already mentioned, transforming the system to the standard form required by ODE solver can be time consuming. (`difforder = 2; points = 100` is already challenging for the method above. ) So</strike> `MassMatrix` method shown above turns out to be very efficient for the problem. Still, it's not a bad idea to leave `NDSolve` alone and turn to pure finite difference method (FDM) as I've done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183767/1871). I'll use `pdetoae` for the task:

```
(* Definitions for feq etc. are the same as above. *)
Clear[domain, points, grid];
domain@t = {0, Tend}; domain@y = {-1, 1};
points@t = 100; points@y = 100;
difforder = 4;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {t, y};
var = Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {η, v}, grid@t, grid@y];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{η, v}[t, y], grid /@ {t, y}, difforder];
delone = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
deltwo = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
ae@1 = delone /@ Rest@ptoafunc@feq[[1]];
ae@2 = deltwo /@ Rest@ptoafunc@feq[[2]];
aeic@1 = delone@ptoafunc@fic[[1]];
aeic@2 = deltwo@ptoafunc@fic[[2]];
aebc = ptoafunc@fbc;

{barray, marray} = 
  CoefficientArrays[{Outer[#@#2 &, {ae, aeic}, {1, 2}], aebc} // Flatten, var // Flatten];
sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -barray];
```

> **Remark**
>
> If you have difficulty in understanding the usage of `Rest`, `delone`
> and `deltwo`, the following is an alternative that doesn't require you
> to remove equations from the system:
>
> ```
> fullsys = ptoafunc@{feq, fic, fbc};
> {barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[fullsys // Flatten, var // Flatten];
> sollst = LeastSquares[marray, -barray, Method -> Direct]; // AbsoluteTiming
> ```
>
> Notice this approach is slower.

```
solfunclst = 
  ListInterpolation[#, grid /@ {t, y}] & /@ ArrayReshape[sollst, {2, points@t, points@y}];
Clear[u1, u3]
u1[t_, y_] = I/α D[v[t, y], y] /. v -> solfunclst[[2]];
u3[t_, y_] = I/α η[t, y] /. η -> solfunclst[[1]];
```

The resulting pictures look the same as above so I'd like to omit them here.

Comment: very helpful. With your `pdetoode` weapon, is there still any possibility to call the method of `"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"`? After testing, with `difforder=2`, the method fails with `point` up to about 90.

Comment: @jsxs Sadly it's impossible, because `"DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"` doesn't accept symbolic input. (The reason might be symbolic calculation for `"Pseudospectral"` is too expensive. ) Try the new added FDM solution, this should allow you to choose a denser spatial grid.

Comment: thanks a lot! It's going to take me a while to understand the method. Btw, does the number of points include the boundaries of $y\in[-1,1]$. In other word, if points=51, we have 50 intervals?

Comment: @jsxs Yes, just execute `grid@y` and observe.

Comment: After testing, I found that `pdetoae` uses more memory, even becomes slower than the partly-NDSolve method, especially for a large Tend and small timestep, say `Tend=200` with `points@t = 200`. In the FDM, we explicitly fixed the timestep using `points@t` and solve a linear system **at one stroke**, while the partial-NDSolve method calculates the problem iteratively. So the latter may slower but use less memory and FDM may fail for too many time grid. Btw can we find out what timestep was choose by `NDSolveValue` for integration?

Comment: @jsxs The main bottleneck here is actually `pdetoae`, because it generates symbolic difference equation for every grid points. It's possible to build a more memory-efficient coefficient array generator, but that'll be even more advanced and I'd like not to try it at the moment. So, I recommend you to turn to a simpler but effective enough solution: first calculate for a smaller `Tend`, and use the solution at `Tend` as i.c. and start the solver once again. As to the time step chosen by `NDSolve`, I don't think it's possible to predict it.

Comment: Thank you very much. About 'using the soln of a previous `NDSolve` as a new IC of the next run', could u plz provide a hint or a link for such kind of case? Do we need a `For` loop to this end? I just noted that I have not accepted your answer. So sorry!

Comment: I have some trouble in the plotting: `v[t, y] = v[t, y] /. v -> fsol[[2]]; u1[t, y] = I/α D[v[t, y], y] /. v -> fsol[[2]]; try[t_] = NIntegrate[
   Conjugate[{u1[t, y], v[t, y]}].{u1[t, y], v[t, y]}, {y, -1, 1}]; Plot[try[t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, Tend}]` The `plot` gave the error:>inumr: The integrand <<1>> has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries, with an empty plot. Could u help?

Comment: @jsxs **Don't use `For`**, try `NestList`, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/1871) for more information. As to the 2nd question, try the following and make sure you've understand the reasons for every modification: `Clear[v, u1, try];
vsol[t_, y_] = v[t, y] /. v -> fsol[[2]]; 
u1[t_, y_] = I/\[Alpha] D[v[t, y], y] /. v -> fsol[[2]]; 
try[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Conjugate[{u1[t, y], vsol[t, y]}].{u1[t, y], vsol[t, y]}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];

Plot[try[t], {t, 0, Tend}] // Quiet // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: Thank you for your help. To make the soln. fit the b.c. better, I have chosen `sf=5`. However, if I specified `Method`, e.g. `NDSolveValue[{ode /@ {1, 2}, odeic, odebc}, var, {t, 0, Tend}, 
 Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> Automatic}];` Should I need do some change e.g. something like `"ScaleFactor" -> 5` as you did with `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}`

Comment: @jsxs No, notice `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"` is a sub-option for `"MethodOfLines"`, and in the current solution, the variable `sf` has played the role of `"ScaleFactor"`.

Comment: Thank you again @xzczd I want to observe the time step chosen by `NDSolve` in your partly-NDSolve method, I tried `ListLinePlot[
 Reap[NDSolveValue[{Map[ode, {1, 2}], odeic, odebc}, 
    var, {t, 0, Tend}, StepMonitor :> Sow[{t, fsol[[2]]}]]][[2, 1]]]`, in which `Sow[{t, fsol[[2]]}]` has been used to plot the stepsize in the time integration for `v`. But the ``ListLinePlot` gave an empty fig...

Comment: @jsxs ……You're using `StepMonitor` blindly. `fsol` isn't defined in your code at all, how can you extract time step with it? And, if you just want to check the time step, there's no need to extract it with the monitor, just extract the information from the `InterpolatingFunction`. I've already used this technique in the `rebuild` function above. If you have difficulty in understanding it, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043/1871).

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again. I am having difficulty in obtaining the Max and the corresponding position from the soln, since the _structure_ of the soln obtained seems different from that of the built-in Solver. E.g. for $\eta$ `\[Eta]sol[t_, y_] = \[Eta][t, y] /. \[Eta] -> solfunclst[[1]];` then `NMaximize[\[Eta]sol[Tend, y] // Abs // Evaluate, y]` gives me > {Abs[InterpolatingFunction[{
{0., 20.}, {-1., 1}},<>] [20, y]], {y -> -8.28999}}. Also, obviously the $y$-value is out of range.

Comment: @jsxs "…the structure of the soln obtained seems different from that of the built-in Solver" No, there's no difference, the erroneous output is caused by a possible bug of `NMaximize`. Actually in _v11.2_ `NMaximize` will spit out `NMaximize::cvmit` warning and a more erroneous output `{-Experimental\`NumericalFunction[……`. Two workarounds I can think out at the moment: 1. Use `FindMaximum` instead. 2. Use `Abs` before interpolating: `ηtest = 
  ListInterpolation[ArrayReshape[sollst, {2, points@t, points@y}][[1]] // Abs, 
   grid /@ {t, y}];
NMaximize[{ηtest[Tend, y], -1 <= y <= 1}, y]
`

Comment: @jsxs The bug of `NMaximize` seems to be fixed in _v12_.

Comment: @jsxs Today I notice the `MassMatrix` method is a much better choice for solving the ODE system. See my update.