# Nonlinear elasticity PDE in Mathematica 12

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

Mathematica 12, Windows 10.

I am trying to solve a PDE in one spatial dimension $R$ and time $t$. I need a solution for displacement $r(R,t)$, radial Cauchy stress $T_{RR}(R,t)$, and radial growth $\gamma_{RR}(R,t)$.

To make things as simple as possible, I first write the static version of the system (two coupled ODEs), making sure we get a solution. Then I add a trivial time evolution turning it into a PDE, and hopefully we can figure out the problem together.

**Static problem (coupled ODEs)**

```
 γRR[R_, t_] := 3 
γθθ[R_, t_] := 4

eqns = {
  r[R, t] D[r[R, t], R] == γRR[R, t] γθθ[
     R, t] R,
  r[R, t]^4  R γθθ[R, t] D[TRR[R, t], R] == 
   2 γRR[R, 
     t] (r[R, t]^4 - R^4 γθθ[R, t]^4) 
  }

ic = {r[0.1, t] == 0.1, TRR[1, t] == 0}

sol = First@NDSolve[{eqns, ic}, {r[R, t], TRR[R, t]}, {R, 0.1, 1}]

PlotSol[sol_] := 
 Plot[{r[R, t], TRR[R, t]} /. sol /. t -> 1 // Evaluate, {R, 0.1, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"R", None}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"r(R)", "TRR(R)"}, {Center, Top}]]
PlotSol@sol
```

The solution is as expected:

[image]

**Dynamic problem (PDE)**

Now I simply add a trivial equation to the system of differential equations: The time derivative of $\gamma_{RR}$ is zero, that is $\dot{\gamma}_{RR}=0$. I amend the initial conditions with $\gamma_{RR}(R, t=0)=3$, which of course completely decouples and should give the same result as in the ODE example. I now `NDSolve` now over a domain in both $R$ and $t$:

```
Clear@γRR

AppendTo[eqns, D[γRR[R, t], t] == 0]

AppendTo[ic, γRR[R, 0] == 3 ]

sol = First@
  NDSolve[{eqns, ic}, {r[R, t], TRR[R, t]}, {R, 0.1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
PlotSol@sol
```

However, unexpectedly, I get some error messages from the `NDSolve` and the correct solution is not returned:

[image]

What is going on here? I added a trivial uncoupled set of equations which should not have changed the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `NDSolve` is using different method for these 2 problems. For the first problem, `Shooting` method, which is for nonlinear boundary value problem of ordinaray differential equation, is used; while for the second problem, `FiniteElement` method, which supports nonlinear problem as of *v12*, is used. Different solvers of `NDSolve` are not equally powerful. For the second problem, we can obtain a result by adjusting the option a little. (The result is not perfect though):

```
sol = First@
  NDSolve[{eqns, ic}, {r[R, t], TRR[R, t], γRR}, {R, 0.1, 1}, {t, 0, 1},
          InitialSeeding -> {r[R,t] == 3, TRR[R,t] == 3, γRR[R,t] == 2},
          Method -> {FiniteElement, MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05}]
PlotSol@sol
```

[image]

"Then, is it possible to avoid using pure `FiniteElement`in `NDSolve`?" Well, for this specific toy problem, if we differentiate the first 2 equations in `t` direction and add proper initial condition, it's possible:

```
γθθ[R_, t_] := 4
tend = 1;
bleft = 1/10; bright = 1;
With[{r = r[R, t], TRR = TRR[R, t], γRR = γRR[R, t], γθθ = γθθ[R, t]},

  eqns = {r D[r, R] == γRR γθθ R,
          r^4 R γθθ D[TRR, R] == 2 γRR (r^4 - R^4 γθθ^4),
          D[γRR, t] == 0};

  bc = {r == 0.1 /. R -> bleft, TRR == 0 /. R -> bright};

  ic = γRR == 3 /. t -> 0;];

Block[{γRR}, γRR[R_, t_] := 3; 
  solinitlst = 
   NDSolveValue[{eqns // Most, bc}, {r[R, t], TRR[R, t]}, {R, bleft, bright}]];

icadd = {r[R, 0], TRR[R, 0]} == solinitlst;

sollst = NDSolveValue[{D[eqns // Most, t], eqns // Last, bc, ic, icadd}, {r, 
    TRR, γRR}, {t, 0, tend}, {R, bleft, bright}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 50, 
       "MinPoints" -> 50, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}];

Plot[sollst[R, tend] // Through // Evaluate, {R, bleft, bright}]
```

[image]

Notice this approach will probably fail in more complicated cases, because the DAE solver `NDSolve` is not that strong. In those cases, advanced technique is needed, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184285/1871) is an example.

Comment: (+1), it's usually better to solve time dependent problems with the method of lines and FEM/TGP as a spatial discretization then as a pure spatial problem like done here. Usually specifying Method->"MethofOfLInes" then indicates some setup problem for the time dependent problem and is ultimately the reason a pure spatial FEM as chosen.

Comment: So, for a problem like this, would it be best to use NDSolve only for the spatial problem (say, with default properties, like in my ODE example) and then write a loop (say simple Euler scheme) iterating over time? Or is there a magic NDSolve trick that could specify different methods for spatial and temporal integration as options?

Comment: @AlexanderErlich "……Euler scheme……" I doubt, because we need to transform the system to the _standard form_ required by Euler scheme, which is not easy for the specific problem. (Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871) “…magic `NDSolve` trick…" There doesn't seem to be, because `NDSolve` is having difficulty in noticing `MethodOfLines` can be used in `t` direction. (Adding `Method -> {MethodOfLines, TemporalVariable -> t}` causes `tvic` warning. )

Comment: @AlexanderErlich Anyway, I've added a solution for the toy example forcing `NDSolve` to use DAE solver in `t` direction. It'll probably fail for more complicated problem, though.