# Solving complex differential equation with ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to solve a complex differential equation for the function $S(u,v)$ depending on the parameter $\omega$. The code is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
m = 100;
L = 2;
r[u_, v_] = 2 m (1 + ProductLog[- ((u v)/E)]);
F[u_, v_] = (32 m^3)/r[u, v]^3 Exp[-(r[u, v]/(2 m))];
Vz[u_, v_] = FullSimplify [-2 (D[F[u, v], u] D[F[u, v], v])/F[u, v] + 
    4 D[r[u, v], u, v]/r[u, v] + 2/F[u, v] D[F[u, v], u, v] + 
    2/F[u, v] D[F[u, v], u] D[r[u, v], v] + 
    2/F[u, v] D[F[u, v], v] D[r[u, v], u]];
Z[u_, v_] = Exp[-I (u + v)/2 ω] S[u, v];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[Z[u, v], u, v] + 
     F[u, v] (L (L + 1))/r[u, v]^2 Z[u, v] + Z[u, v] Vz[u, v] == 0, 
   S[u, -1] == 1, S[1, v] == 1}, 
  S, {u, 1, 100}, {v, -100, -1}, ω]
```

I get the error

> ParametricNDSolveValue::mconly: "For the method !("IDA"), only
> machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values
> or beyond floating-point exceptions"

So it seems that Mathematica expects real numbers, but it finds complex numbers instead. How can I solve the differential equation?

Comment: Do you expect `S` to be real?

Comment: @bbgodfrey no it is immaginary

Comment: Do you mean  that `I S` is real?  In any case, it may be possible to split the PDE into two coupled real PDEs, which may resolve the problem.  Also you may find [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184285/1063) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can be addressed by solving for `Z` rather than `S`, splitting the PDE into its real and imaginary parts, and later constructing `S` if desired.

```
solr[ω_] := NDSolveValue[{D[Z[u, v], u, v] + 
    F[u, v] (L (L + 1))/r[u, v]^2 Z[u, v] + Z[u, v] Vz[u, v] == 0, 
    Z[u, -1] == Cos[1/2 (-1 + u) ω], Z[1, v] == Cos[1/2 (1 + v) ω]}, 
    Z, {u, 1, 2}, {v, -2, -1}]
soli[ω_] := NDSolveValue[{D[Z[u, v], u, v] + 
    F[u, v] (L (L + 1))/r[u, v]^2 Z[u, v] + Z[u, v] Vz[u, v] == 0, 
    Z[u, -1] == -Sin[1/2 (-1 + u) ω], Z[1, v] == -Sin[1/2 (1 + v) ω]}, 
    Z, {u, 1, 2}, {v, -2, -1}]

zr = solr[1];
Plot3D[zr[u, v], {u, 1, 2}, {v, -2, -1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {u, v, z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

```
zi = soli[1];
Plot3D[zi[u, v], {u, 1, 2}, {v, -2, -1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {u, v, z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Black, Bold}]
```

[image]

Two notes.  First, the integration ranges of `u` and `v` have been greatly reduced, because the solution grows exponentially large otherwise, and `Plot3D` fails.  Second, using `ParametricNDSolveValue` instead of `SetDelayed` and `NDSolveValue` causes the kernel to crash.