# ParametricNDSolveValue causes kernel to crash

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 12.1.1 and persisting through 13.2.0.**

---

In the course of answering question [228693](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228781/1063), I found that

```
ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[z[u, v], u, v] + z[u, v] == 0, z[u, -1] == Cos[1/2 (-1 + u) ω],
    z[1, v] == Cos[1/2 (1 + v) ω]}, z, {u, 1, 2}, {v, -2, -1}, {ω}]
%[1]
```

produces what appears to be to be a valid `ParametricFunction` but then causes the kernel to crash.  (Incidentally, replacing `z[u, -1] == Cos[1/2 (-1 + u) ω]` by `z[u, -1] == 1` and `z[1, v] == Cos[1/2 (1 + v) ω]` by `z[1, v] == 1` eliminates the problem.)  In contrast,

```
NDSolveValue[{D[z[u, v], u, v] + z[u, v] == 0, z[u, -1] == Cos[1/2 (-1 + u) ω], 
    z[1, v] == Cos[1/2 (1 + v) ω]} /. ω -> 1, z, {u, 1, 2}, {v, -2, -1}]
```

is well behaved.  Is this a bug, or am I missing something obvious?  I am using

```
$Version
(* "12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)
```

**Some additional observations:**

Several comments below plus my own  more recent observations may be worth considering.

1. Ulrich Neumann pointed out, and I have confirmed, that adding `Method-> "FiniteElement"` allows the first block of code above to produce a solution.  Unfortunately, the solution is incorrect.  For completeness, the solution I believe to be correct is below.
2. Bob Hanlon pointed out, and I have confirmed, that adding `WorkingPrecison` with most any numerical value, including `$MachingPrecison`, causes the second block of code above to fail.
3. The notebook I first used to demonstrate the kernel crash no longer causes that crash.  However, copying the first block of code from the question to a new notebook and running it again produces the crash.  More generally, I now have observed that the crash, although typical, is not always reproducible.
4. When I monitored the notebook with the first block of code by means of Microsoft Task Manager, sometimes Mathematica hangs, sometimes not.

[image]

Comment: Even the case z[u,-1] == 1 causes the kernel crash for me and I have exactly same setup as you with Windows 10 (and I restarted MMA clean on each try).

Comment: `Method-> "FiniteElement"`  gives a stable but somewhat strange  parametric solution.

Comment: @Moo  Thanks for catching my error, now corrected.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  I just plotted the solution with `Method-> "FiniteElement"`.  It looks very unstable.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, not very smooth, but satisfies the boundary conditions !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  So does the `NDSolveValue` result from my question, but the plot is smooth.

Comment: With v12.1.1 on a Mac and using `NDSolveValue`, when I attempt to set the `WorkingPrecision` I get one or more errors. The specific errors vary depending on the `WorkingPrecision` specified.

Comment: @BobHanlon  I get `NDSolveValue::initf` with the message, "The initialization of the method NDSolve StateSpace failed" in all cases, when I specify `WorkingPrecision`.  Incidentally, it is easy to guess analytic solutions to the PDE, but `DSolve` does not return any.

Comment: The crash has been reported.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielLichtblau.  There are even more problems here.  Using `Method-> "FiniteElement"` eliminates the crash but produces a nonsense answer.  The notebook from which I produced the question now no longer exhibits the crash, but a new notebook with the code does.  When I monitor the notebook with Microsoft Task Manager, sometimes Mathematica hangs, sometimes not.  And, setting `WorkingPrecision` to any value causes `NDSolveValue` applied to the PDE generate an initialization error.  This PDE seems cursed.