# Understanding NDSolve::ndmmc

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, undocumented

When running `NDSolve` with `Method->{"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"}` I frequently encounter this error:

> NDSolveValue::ndmmc: The mass matrix `SparseArray[…]`
> should be a constant numerical matrix.
> The option `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}` can be used
> to solve the equations as a system of differential-algebraic equations.

Which is quite annoying because there is zero documentation on this topic, so I have no idea how to debug the code. In fact, what is a "constant numerical matrix" is not even clear.

I've searched across Mathematica's documentation and this is the closest I've found:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html

But it is unlikely that a constant numerical matrix refers to a matrix of only 1 type of element, especially for equation solving.

I would therefore like to ask

1. What is a constant numerical matrix?
2. Why does `NDSolve` fail to generate constant numerical matrices under `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"MassMatrix"}` under certain conditions?
3. In general, what can we do to resolve such error?

Thanks in advance to all the help offered!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, `MassMatrix` method isn't well documented, but this warning isn't hard to understand.

According to the tutorial [*Numerical Solution of Differential-Algebraic Equations*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html#990919154), `MassMatrix` is a method that transforms the equation(s) to the form $M.x'=F(x,t)$, but what's undocumented is, the $M$ matrix must be a *constant numerical matrix*. What's *constant numerical matrix*? It's better to explain with a minimal example. Suppose we want to solve

$$t\ x'(t)-1=0,\ x(2)=3,\ t\in[2,4]$$

with `MassMatrix` method, how should we transform the ODE to the required $M.x'=F(x,t)$ form? Clearly the most straightforward transformation would be $(t).(x'(t))=(1)$ (`{{t}}.{x'[t]} == {1}`) i.e. $M=(t)$ (`M = {{t}}`). This is exactly what happens in `NDSolve`:

```
asso = NDSolve[{t x'[t] - 1 == 0, x[2] == 3}, x, {t, 2, 4}, 
   Method -> EquationSimplification -> MassMatrix] // EvaluationData
```

> NDSolve::ndmmc

```
asso["MessagesExpressions"][[1, 1, -1, 1]] // Normal
(* {{t}} *)
```

> **Remark**
>
> If I have to guess, `NDSolve` might have used something similar to
>
> ```
> CoefficientArrays[{t x'[t] - 1 == 0}, {x'[t]}] // Last
> ```
>
> to generate the mass matrix, but `TraceInternal` doesn't confirm it.

The $M$ involves symbolic variable $t$ (`t`) so it's not **numerical**. "But once the numeric ODE/DAE solver starts working, $t$ will be numerical at every time step!" Yeah, but it varies as time changes i.e. the matrix won't be **constant**. I'm not knowledge enough to explain why `MassMatrix` is designed not to allow such matrix, though.

"OK, then how to circumvent this? " In many cases, we can simply help the coefficient extractor a bit. For example, the example above can be transformed to

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] - 1/t == 0, x[2] == 3}, x, {t, 2, 4}, 
 Method -> EquationSimplification -> MassMatrix]
```

"Wait, isn't this ridiculous? Why not directly set `EquationSimplification -> Solve`? That'll automatically transform the equation to `x'[t] == 1/t`!" Yeah, `MassMatrix` method doesn't show any advantage for this toy example. But when the system gets large (this happens quite a bit when symbolically discretizing PDE), the `EquationSimplification -> Solve` may be too expensive for symbolic pre-processing, while `EquationSimplification -> Residual` may be too weak to handle the resulting system, then `MassMatrix` method becomes an appreciable method. That's the reason I sometimes set this option when solving ODE systems generated by `pdetoode`. Typical example:

[Why does NDSolve fail to solve the PDEs and spit out mconly warning?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184281/1871)

> **Remark**
>
> For those who feel the toy *system* $(t).(x'(t))=(1)$ with only one
> equation inside uncomfortabe, here's a slightly more complicated toy
> example:
>
> ```
> NDSolve[{{(t + 1) (x'[t] + y'[t]) == (t + 1) (Sin[t] - z'[t]), 
>                     y'[t] + z'[t] == Sin[t] + x[t], 
>                     x'[t] + z'[t] == y[t] + Cos[t]}, 
>          {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}}, 
>          {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1}, 
>         Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"}]
> ```
>
> > NDSolve::ndmmc
>
> Notice this is essentially the documented example for `MassMatrix`, except that I've multiplied each side of the first equation
> by `(t + 1)`, yet this is enough to fool the pre-processor of
> `MassMatrix`.