Unable to solve set of partial differential problems (coupled)
First, I'd like to apologize for any mistakes as this is my first time asking this question. I have a set of PDEs, and I am unable to solve them using NDSolve in Mathematica.
The problem is related to adsorption

$\rho$ (rho) is amount in bulk phase, $q$ (q) here is amount in adsorbed phase. The dependent variable $z$ in governing equation is replaced by x in code (spatial parameter).
The boundary condition that i want to put for this problem is:

flow from $x=0$ and passing through from $x=l$.

Insulated boundary at $x=l$.

Temperature at $x=0$ is incoming fluid temperature.


Below is my code:
 e0 = 0.3; 
rhos = 340; 
mn2 = 28.0134; 
di = 25.6/10^3; 
d0 = 28.2/10^3; 
l = 225/10^3; 
a1 = (Pi*di^2)/4; 
a2 = Pi*d0*l; 
a = a1 + a2; 
cps = 0.7039; 
rg = 0.3; 
delh = 12*10^3; 
conds = 0.001; 
h = 0.012; 
t0 = 312; 
htinput = 0; 
htdia = 0.005; 
htl = 200/10^3; 
cp = 1.0943; 
qmax = 96; 
n = 0.85; 
e1 = 1850000000; 
e2 = -3.7462; 
ki = 0.04848; 
dp = 0.005; 
mu = 18.438/10^6; 
massbalance = D[rho[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t]*rho[x, t], x] + ((1 - e0)/e0)*rhos*mn2*D[q[x, t], t] == 0; 

energybalance = (a1/a)*cp*rho[x, t]*D[temp[x, t], t] + (a1/a)*((1 - e0)/e0)*rhos*cps*D[temp[x, t], t] - rg*rho[x, t]*D[temp[x, t], t] - 
     ((1 - e0)/e0)*delh*rhos*D[q[x, t], t] == (a1/(a*e0))*conds*D[D[temp[x, t], x], x] - cp*rho[x, t]*D[u[x, t]*temp[x, t], x] - 
     ((4*h)/(e0*d0))*(temp[x, t] - t0) + (4*htinput)/(Pi*htdia^2*htl); 
     
ldf = D[q[x, t], t] == ki*(qmax*((e1*temp[x, t]^e2*p[x, t])^(1/n)/(1 + (e1*temp[x, t]^e2*p[x, t])^(1/n))/(mn2*1000)) - q[x, t]); 

ergun = D[p[x, t], x] == ((((1 - e0)*u[x, t])/(dp*e0^3))*((150*mu*(1 - e0))/dp + (7*rho[x, t]*u[x, t])/4))/10^6; 

eos = p[x, t] == (rho[x, t]*rg*temp[x, t])/1000; 

ics = {temp[x, 0] == 312, rho[x, 0] == 1.123, q[x, 0] == 0}; 
bcs = {rho[0, t] == 32.425, u[0, t] == 0.05, temp[0, t] == 312, Derivative[1, 0][temp][l, t] == 0, p[l, t] == 0.1}; 


NDSolve[{massbalance, energybalance, ergun, ldf, eos, ics, bcs}, {u, q, temp, p, rho}, {x, 0, l}, {t, 0, 10}];

From my understanding, the number of boundary or initial conditions required for a variable in a partial differential equation (PDE) depends on the order of the differential equation and the independent variable. However, this approach doesn’t seem to be working in my case. Could you please advise on how to solve this problem? Do I need to adjust my boundary or initial conditions?
If you need any more clarification please let me know.

Hello, welcome to MMA.SE. 1. The question will be more attractive with more specific background info. 2. femcnsd is triggered because NDSolve doesn't see enough explicit i.c.s (yeah mathematically the i.c.s are enough but NDSolve cannot figure it out). 3. ergun is troublesome, it doesn't involve derivative of t but involves derivative of $z$ (x) triggering the DAE solver. My personal experience is, pure FDM is more suitable for this type of problem. 4. Are you sure the problem itself (including those parameters) is correct? I tried pure FDM, the problem seems to be ill-posed.

@xzczd thank you replying 1.The problem is a fixed bed adsorption(i cannot explain much as i have wordlimitoncomment sorry) 2. Are you suggesting me to add ics and bcs for all dependent variables present 3.if we had a pressure derivative with respect to t will it be helpful as we can use eos and differentiate wrt time 3.Can we solve FDM in Mathematica as it used FEM 4.Sorry, there were some errors in parameters and now i have corrected them(unit issue). If you have suggestions on how to solve this problem is really appreciated as i am stuck with this for a long time (alternate ways of approach


"Are you suggesting me to add ics and bcs" No, I'm just explaining why you've seen the warning. Adding i.c.s and b.c.s to make NDSolve choosing MethodOfLines isn't necessarily a good idea. 6. "we can use eos and differentiate wrt time" Usually this won't help, ergun is still in the way. 7. In the updated code, rho[x, 0] == 1.123 but rho[0, t] == 32.425, is it intentional? 8. "flow from $x=0$
and passing through from $x=l$" Do you mean it's actually an open boundary problem? 9. Are you reproducing certain result from literature? If so, can you add the reference?



"Can we solve FDM in Mathematica" FDM isn't a built-in method of NDSolve, I have self-made tool facilitating the implementation, though. See e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184285/1871 But I believe the most important thing to do at the moment is to make sure the problem itself is indeed correct.


@xzczd
7.i have a different problem but i was trying to replicate the following paper https://doi.org/10.1016/j.applthermaleng.2013.03.005 .So the equations and boundary conditions are taken by this paper only . You will get a clear idea if you refer this. Thank you.


The paper mentions that "The Euler implicit method and central difference
scheme have been adopted", these are primary method for PDE solving. If it's true, something is still wrong with the problem itself, I'm afraid. 12. The paper mentions that "u in the theoretical calculations has been obtained using the valve equation suggested in Refs [19,21,22]" which seems to suggest the velocity is calculated separately. But glancing over [19, 21, 22], it's not immediately clear to me how the velocity is calculated. (I fail to find Ergun equation in these references, BTW. )



Compared to the original one, you've omitted the $D_{\text{ax}}$ term in your model. This will make the system more stiff than the original one. Roughly speaking, pure first-order PDE is also troublesome. If this omission is not necessary, you'd better add it back.

